# Calculus of variations -- how does it make sense to vary the position and the velocity independently?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, differentiation, variational-principle, variational-calculus

In the calculus of variations, particularly Lagrangian mechanics, people often say we vary the position and the velocity independently. But velocity is the derivative of position, so how can you treat them as independent variables?

Comment: Superb question aksink about the very fundament of everything we calculate. Furthermore - provoking great answers. You are very welcome to share your doubts with us @grizzly adam :) Greets

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/60706/ , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/119992/

Comment: I have worried about this for years, it stopped me dead when trying to learn applied mathematics and I have met really good pure mathematicians who were similarly troubled.
One explanation which makes some sense to me is in the cheap book "Classical Mechanics - the theoretical minimum" which uses a school-like, infinitesimal, approach, to my mind answering a question the author does not actually pose.
Thanks for posting this question.

Comment: Related questions on Math.SE: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1798396/11127 , https://math.stackexchange.com/q/580858/11127

Comment: I recommend you take a look at Burke's book [*Applied Differential Geometry*](https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9781139171786)  (Cambridge U. Press 1987). Consider that its dedication in the front pages says this: "*To all those who, like me, have wondered how in hell you can change $q$ without changing $\dot{q}$.*" :)

Answer (score 93):

Unlike your question suggests, it is *not* true that velocity is varied independently of position. A variation of position $q \mapsto q + \delta q$ induces a variation of velocity $\partial_t q \mapsto \partial_t q + \partial_t (\delta q)$ as you would expect.

The only thing that may seem strange is that $q$ and $\partial_t q$ are treated as independent variables of the Lagrangian $L(q,\partial_t q)$. But this is not surprising; after all, if you ask "what is the kinetic energy of a particle?", then it is not enough to know the position of the particle, you also have to know its velocity to answer that question.

Put differently, you can choose position and velocity independently as *initial conditions*, that's why the Lagrangian function treats them as independent; but the calculus of variation does *not vary them independently*, a variation in position induces a fitting variation in velocity.

Comment: To be more precise: it is not only about having to choose independent initial conditions. Velocities and positions as coordinates are always independent *unless* we are on a solution of the equation of motion. That is, $v^j=\dot{q}^j$ only on the trajectories that solve the Euler-Lagrangian equations. Onto those, variations of the former imply variations of the latter. Elsewhere they are unrelated.

Comment: Please explain the first few lines. Position and velocity are independent. They depend explicitly only on time. They off course depend implicitly on each other but not at all explicitly. You van not change v by jus changing x alone. When you change x it is understood that t changes. It is because of that change in t that v changes. Essentially the partiality derivative of v with x is 0 but the derivative of v with x is not 0. That is why, I think we don't apply any " chain rule " here !

Comment: @Shashaank  the derivative of v with respect to x **is** 0.

Comment: @Greg Graviton So according to your answer, if I can choose acceleration independently, then will it also be treated as an independent variable?

Comment: @Theoretical In principle, the Lagrangian may depend on acceleration as well, e.g. be represented by a function $L(q,v,a)$ where $q,v,a$ are independent variables. However, it is only evaluated on curves $q(t)$ where $q\equiv q(t)$, $v \equiv \partial_t q(t)$ and $a \equiv \partial^2_t q(t)$.

Comment: I'm somewhat convinced by the explanation by @gented. But yet I cant help wringing my hands in frustration. I've gone thru Goldstein etc, they just gloss over this. Surely this conceptual leap of thought deserved ample discussion in the text. Fine, even if we go with what gented says (in other words, $q$ and $qdot$ are dependent albeit only when on the solution path), what still bothers me is this: Doesn't it yet have to be consistent? As in, after solving for the path, normally if we retrace our Math steps then we'd normally expect every step to be satisfied. Doesn't seem to be the case here.

Comment: For example, if $f = q_1^2t^3 + q_2^2t^2$. Suppose $q_1$ and $q_2$ are functions of time (that are unknown apriori but get known after solving the problem). Then, is it correct to say that $\frac{\partial(f)}{\partial(q_1)} = 2q_1t^3$, as all the justifications heretofore would have one believe? Well, that doesn't seem to be right if the solution was eventually found to be say $q_1(t)=t$. If we substitute this in $f$, we get $f=q_1^5 + q_1^2q_2^2$, and *then* calculate $\frac{\partial(f)}{\partial(q_1)}$, that gives a totally different value. How does one explain this?

Comment: @vharihar In this, case the issue is actually with the partial derivative — it is not stable under a change of variables! Consider for example $g(x,y)$. The partial derivative $\partial g/\partial x_{y=\text{const}}$ is different from the partial derivative $\partial g/\partial x_{z=\text{const}}$ where $z=y-x$.

Comment: I have gone through the answer and the comments but again I wouldn't say I'm entirely convinced. I know that whether you're at (1,1) or (100,100), a velocity of 5i+2j remains 5i+2j.  This may not be the case for the same points in,say,spherical polar coordinates. However I am not being able dismiss the following idea: $x=t$ and $v=t^2$ which means $v=x^2$ or $\frac{df}{dx} \neq 0$. Can you give a convincing argument against this?

Comment: @AmbicaGovind You need to give a more well-defined statement to argue for or against. You have not defined $f$, do you mean $v$? Could you rewrite `\frac{dv}{dx}` in terms of its definition as limit, with particular attention to which of the variables $t$ or $x$ varies, and which does not?

Comment: @gented is incorrect. You can have paths where $v = \dot q$ that do not solve the Euler Lagrange equations that are just not stationary with respect to the action. Greg stated it correctly.

Answer (score 50):

The answer to your main question is already given -- you do not *vary* coordiante and speed independently. But it seems that your main problem is about using coordinate and speed as independent variables.

Let me refer to this great book:
["Applied Differential Geometry". By William L. Burke](http://books.google.com/books?id=58SFj9x5RMEC&printsec=frontcover&hl=en#v=onepage&q&f=false). The very first line of the book (where an author usually says to whom this book is devoted) is this:

[image: William Burke]

It is true that from time to time student do ask this question. But attempts to explain it "top down" are usually just lead to more and more questions. One really needs to make mathematical "bottom up" order in the topic. Well, as the name of the book suggest -- the mathematical discipline one needs is [differential geometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_geometry).

I cannot retell all the details, but briefly it looks like this:

- You start with a configuration space $M$ of your system. $M$ is a (differentiable) [manifold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_manifold), and $q$ are the coordinates on this manifold.
- Then there is a specific procedure, that allows you to add all the possible "speeds" at every given point of $M$. And you arrive at the [tangent bundle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_bundle) $TM$, which is a manifold too, and ($q$,$\dot{q}$) are different coordinates on it.
- Lagrangian is a function on $TM$.

Comment: I have this book and tried to read it. But it lacks clear definitions, and I found it to be more frustrating than enlightening. Additionally, I don't believe that it is necessary to know differential geometry to understand calculus of variations. That's like saying that you can't understand arithmetic unless you know set theory.

Comment: First of all, as I said, you are mixing up two different points: about variational calculs and about independence of speeds and coordinates. Second -- I didn't say that you have to read only one book to understand DG.

Comment: I think to really appreciate Lagrangian and Hamiltonian mechanics you **do** need to understand some differential geometry. Arnold says in his book *Mathematical Methods of Classical Mechanics* that "Hamiltonian mechanics cannot be understood without differential forms." This book, by the way, will teach you the differential geometry you need to get started, assuming just some calculus.

Answer (score 27):

Considering what Greg Graviton wrote, I'll write out the derivation and see if I can make sense of it.

$$ S = \int_{t_1}^{t_2} L(q, \dot q, t)\, \mathrm{d}t $$

where S is the action and L the Lagrangian. We vary the path and find the extremum of the action:

$$ \delta S = \int_{t_1}^{t_2} \left({\partial L \over \partial q}\delta q + {\partial L \over \partial \dot q}\delta \dot q\right) \,\mathrm{d}t = 0\,. $$

Here, q and $\dot q$ are varied independently. But then in the next step we use this identity,

$$ \delta \dot q = {\mathrm{d} \over \mathrm{d}t} \delta q. $$

And here is where the relationship between q and $\dot q$ enters the picture. I think that what is happening here is that q and $\dot q$ are treated as independent initially, but then the independence is removed by the identity.

$$ \delta S = \int_{t_1}^{t_2} \left({\partial L \over \partial q}\delta q + {\partial L \over \partial \dot q}{d \over \mathrm{d}t} \delta q\right) \,\mathrm{d}t = 0 $$

And then follows the rest of the derivation. We integrate the second term by parts:

$$ \delta S = \left[ {\partial L \over \partial \dot q}\delta q\right]_{t_1}^{t_2} + \int_{t_1}^{t_2} \left({\partial L \over \partial q} - {d \over dt}{\partial L \over \partial \dot q}\right)\delta q\, \mathrm{d}t = 0\,, $$

and the bracketed expression is zero because the endpoints are held fixed. And then we can pull out the Euler-Lagrange equation:

$$ {\partial L \over \partial q} - {\mathrm{d} \over \mathrm{d}t}{\partial L \over \partial \dot q} = 0\,. $$

Now it makes more sense to me. You start by treating the variables as independent but then remove the independence by imposing a condition *during* the derivation.

I think that makes sense. I expect in general other problems can be treated the same way.

(I copied the above equations from *Mechanics* by Landau and Lifshitz.)

Comment: Well, instead of saying "$q$ and $\dot q$ are varied independently", you could also say "$q$ and $\dot q$ are varied (perhaps independently, perhaps not)" and later note that the variation $\delta\dot q$ is given by $\delta\dot q = \frac d{dt} \delta q$.

Comment: The notation for the arguments $L$ is somewhat confusing, in which case it is instructive to consider the following example: take $F(x,2x-y)$ and vary $F(x+\delta x,2(x+\delta x)-y) = \frac{\partial F}{\partial x}\delta x + \frac{\partial F}{\partial (2x-y)}2\delta x$. You might say that the arguments of $F$ are varied independently, but that sounds weird. If anything, it's just that the notation for the partial derivatives of $F$ is bad; it is much better to write $F(u,v)$ and $(u,v)=(x,2x-y)$ to obtain $\delta F = \frac{\partial F}{\partial u}\delta u + \frac{\partial F}{\partial v}\delta v$

Comment: ... and to express the variations $\delta u$ and $\delta v$ in terms of $\delta x$ afterwards.

Comment: Yes, the notation is confusing. That's another problem.

Comment: Landau is a great mathematical physicist but he's not known as a simple writer :-)

Comment: "Not a word of Landau, not a thought of Lifshitz."

Comment: @grizzlyadam so in the end, they are not independent but can be treated as much because the mathematics prove it, right?

Answer (score 22):

Here is my answer, which is basically an expanded version of Greg Graviton's answer.

The question of why one can treat position and velocity as independent variables arises in the *definition* of the Lagrangian $L$ itself, *before* one uses equation of motion, and *before* one thinks about varying the action $S:=\int_{t_i}^{t_f}\mathrm{d}t \ L$, and has therefore *nothing* to do with calculus of variation.

I) On one hand, let us first consider the role of the Lagrangian.
Let there be given an arbitrary but fixed instant of time $t_0\in [t_i,t_f]$. The (instantaneous) Lagrangian $L(q(t_0),v(t_0),t_0)$ is a function of both the instantaneous position $q(t_0)$ and the instantaneous velocity $v(t_0)$ at the instant $t_0$.
Here $q(t_0)$ and $v(t_0)$ are *independent* variables. Note that the (instantaneous) Lagrangian $L(q(t_0),v(t_0),t_0)$ does not depend on the past $t<t_0$ nor the future $t>t_0$. (One may object that the velocity profile $\dot{q}\equiv\frac{\mathrm{d}q}{\mathrm{d}t}:[t_i,t_f]\to\mathbb{R}$ is the derivative of the position profile $q:[t_i,t_f]\to\mathbb{R}$, so how can $q(t_0)$ and $v(t_0)$ be truly independent variables? The point is that since the equation of motion is of 2nd order, one is still entitled to make 2 *independent* choices of initial conditions: 1 initial position and 1 initial velocity.) We can repeat this argument for any other instant $t_0\in[t_i,t_f]\,.$

II) On the other hand, let us consider calculus of variation.
The action functional
$$S[q] ~:=~ \int_{t_i}^{t_f}\mathrm{d}t \ L(q(t),\dot{q}(t),t)\tag{1}$$
depends on the whole (perhaps virtual) path $q:[t_i,t_f]\to\mathbb{R}$. Here the time derivative $\dot{q}\equiv\frac{\mathrm{d}q}{\mathrm{d}t}$ does *depend* on the function $q:[t_i,t_f]\to \mathbb{R}\,.$ Extremizing the action functional

$$\begin{align}0~=~&\delta S \cr
~=~& \int_{t_i}^{t_f}\mathrm{d}t\left[\left.\frac{\partial L(q(t),v(t),t)}{\partial q(t)}\right|_{v(t)=\dot{q}(t)} \delta q(t) \right.\cr
&+\left.\left.\frac{\partial L(q(t),v(t),t)}{\partial v(t)}\right|_{v(t)=\dot{q}(t)}\delta \dot{q}(t)\right]\cr
 ~=~& \int_{t_i}^{t_f}\mathrm{d}t\left[\left.\frac{\partial L(q(t),v(t),t)}{\partial q(t)}\right|_{v(t)=\dot{q}(t)} \delta q(t) \right.\cr
&+\left.\left.\frac{\partial L(q(t),v(t),t)}{\partial v(t)}\right|_{v(t)=\dot{q}(t)}\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm{d}t}\delta q(t)\right]\cr
~=~& \int_{t_i}^{t_f}\mathrm{d}t\left[\left.\frac{\partial L(q(t),v(t),t)}{\partial q(t)}\right|_{v(t)=\dot{q}(t)} \right.\cr
&-\left. \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm{d}t}\left(\left.\frac{\partial L(q(t),v(t),t)}{\partial v(t)}\right|_{v(t)=\dot{q}(t)} \right)\right]\delta q(t)\cr 
&+ \int_{t_i}^{t_f}\mathrm{d}t\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\left[\left.\frac{\partial L(q(t),v(t),t)}{\partial v(t)}\right|_{v(t)=\dot{q}(t)}\delta q(t)\right] \end{align}\tag{2} $$

with appropriate boundary conditions leads to [Euler-Lagrange (EL) equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation), which is the [equation of motion (EOM)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equations_of_motion).

$$
\begin{align} \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm{d}t}&\left(\left.\frac{\partial L(q(t),v(t),t)}{\partial v(t)}
\right|_{v(t)=\dot{q}(t)} \right)\cr
&~=~ \left.\frac{\partial L(q(t),v(t),t)}{\partial q(t)}
\right|_{v(t)=\dot{q}(t)} ~.\tag{3}\end{align}
$$

III) Note that

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}~=~\dot{v}(t)\frac{\partial}{\partial v(t)}+\dot{q}(t)\frac{\partial}{\partial q(t)}+\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \tag{4}$$

is a *total* time derivative, not an *explicit* time derivative $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}$, so that the EL equation (3) is really a 2nd-order ordinary differential equation (ODE),

$$\begin{align} \left(\ddot{q}(t)\frac{\partial}{\partial v(t)}
+\dot{q}(t)\frac{\partial}{\partial q(t)}
\right.&\left.
+\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\right) \left. \frac{\partial L(q(t),v(t),t)}{\partial v(t)}
\right|_{v(t)=\dot{q}(t)} \cr 
~=~& \left.\frac{\partial L(q(t),v(t),t)}{\partial q(t)}
\right|_{v(t)=\dot{q}(t)}~. \tag{5}\end{align}$$

To solve for the path $q:[t_i,t_f]\to \mathbb{R}$, one should specify two initial conditions, e.g.,
$$q(t_i)~=~q_i\qquad\text{and} \qquad\dot{q}(t_i)~=~v_i.\tag{6}$$

Comment: There might be a better answer in the same line with this post and Christian Blatter's comment https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1211868/603316. The "derivative" between the two function wasn't really derivative of the variables, rather viewed as functional derivative, $\frac{d q(t_2)}{d \dot{q}(t_1)} = \frac{d \int_{\tau}^{t_2} \dot{q}(t) dt}{d \dot{q}(t_1)} =0$ and this was a functional variation.
There might be issue with the contact terms, $\delta(t_1-t_2)$, which was in the region of qm.

Comment: Hi. "We can repeat this argument for any other instant" - I get your point only for the initial conditions. At initial conditions, velocity and position are definitely independent, but not at any other point of time during the path. Can you elaborate ?

Comment: Hi @Chemistry. Thanks for the feedback. There are 2 independent conditions. These 2 can be imposed at any instant $t_0$. They don't have to be at the initial instant.

Comment: @Qmechanic Imagine L being $\frac{1}{2}m\dot q(t)^2 - mgq(t)$ where $q(t)$ and $\dot q(t)$ are functions of t. To know L's value, let's say at $t=2$, you would plug in $t=2$ and get L. This means that behind the hood, the speed that it calculated is dependent on the position,  but note that since $q(t)$ is the path which satisfies the initial conditions at $t=2$, $q(t)$ and $\dot q(t)$ would in turn return the values of that initial conditions for $t=2$, which we can say that at that instant($t=2$), position and speed are still independent. Whatever $t$ you choose, the same logic applies.

Answer (score 9):

While it is true that the function $\dot{q}(t)$ is the derivative of the function $q(t)$ w.r.t. time, it is not true that the value $\dot{q}$ is at all related to the value $q$ at a given point in time, since a value is just a number, not a function.  The action is a functional of $q(t)$, and so it would make no sense to vary the action both w.r.t. $q$ and $\dot{q}$.  But the
Lagrangian $L(q,\dot{q})$ is a function of the values $q$ and $\dot{q}$, not a functional of the functions $q(t)$ and $\dot{q}(t)$.  We can promote $L$ to a function of time if we plug in $q(t)$ and $\dot{q}(t)$ instead of just $q$ and $\dot{q}$.  (Remember a functional turns a function into a number, e.g., $S[q]$, whereas a function turns a value into a number, e.g., $L(q,\dot{q})$.

To solve for $q(t)$ we extremize the action $S$, by demanding that it is extremal at every point, $t$.  This is equivalent to solving the Euler-Lagrange equations at every point $t$.
Since at any point $t$ the values $q$ and $\dot{q}$ are independent, they can be varied independently.

Answer (score 4):

If we have a function $f(x,v)$, the partial derivatives are defined by $$\frac{\partial f(x,v)}{\partial x} \equiv \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h,v)-f(x,v)}{h}$$ and $$\frac{\partial f(x,v)}{\partial v} \equiv \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x,v+h)-f(x,v)}{h}$$ This implies, for example, for $f=v^2$ that $$\frac{\partial v^2}{\partial x} \equiv \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{v^2-v^2}{h} =0.$$ Moreover, for $v= \frac{dx}{dt}$ we find that $x \to x+h$ implies $v = \frac{dx}{dt} \to v' = \frac{d(x+h)}{dt} = \frac{dx}{dt} =v$. Thus $$\frac{\partial \frac{dx}{dt}^2}{\partial x} \equiv \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\frac{dx}{dt}^2-\frac{dx}{dt}^2}{h} =0.$$
Hence it makes sense to consider the partial derivatives of the Lagrangian with respect to $x$ and $v$ separately and in this sense treat them independently.

---

In more physical terms, recall that our goal in the Lagrangian formalism is  to figure out the correct path in configuration space between two fixed location. A path is characterized by a location and velocity at each point in time. We are as general as possible and consider really all possible paths. This implies that we consider all possible pairings of locations and velocities. The physical classical path is special for two reasons:

- it's a solution of the Euler-Lagrange equation (= extremum of the action)
- the locations and velocities at each moment in time are related by $v \equiv \frac{dq}{dt}$. (If you want, $v \equiv \frac{dq}{dt}$ is the second equation that we need in the Lagrangian formalism analogous to how there are two Hamilton equations in the Hamiltonian formalism. The second Hamilton equation defines the canonical momentum as a derivative of the Lagrangian. For general paths in phase space, any pairing of location and momentum is possible. Only for the physical classical path we find canonical momentum values that are given as the appropriate derivative of the Lagrangian.)

Comment: The definition of the partial derivative is a mathematically convincing reason in a way. But I still don't understand how $\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$ can be zero if, for example $v=t^2$ and $x=t$ in which case $v$ can be written as $x^2$

Comment: Because by definition $\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$ means the derivative of $v$ w.r.t. $x$ with $v$ kept constant. If you impose $v = x^2$ then $x^2$ must be kept constant (the appropriate variables are now $x$ and $x^2$) and the derivative is still zero.

Answer (score 2):

The derivative of a function $f(t)$ is the function $\dot{f}(t)$ in general different than $f$, and in the general case the two are not even linearly dependent, which is simple to see if you take the Taylor expansion. It is only after you define differential equations with them that they are linked algebraically, and this is what the calculus of variations does.