# Is this an error?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, symmetry, textbook-erratum

The teacher wrote the following:

[image]

There is a dot missing where the green arrow is, right? After applying Euler's theorem, the term in brackets becomes $x_j$, but we need it to be $\dot{x_j}$, don't we?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/15037/2451

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an equals sign missing: there should be an equals sign to the left of every $\frac m2$, but the third one is missing.

There should *not* be a time-differentiation dot on the $\partial x_j$ under your green arrow.  For dimensional consistency, the terms in the parenthesized summation,
$$
\dot q_k \frac{\partial x_j}{\partial q_k}
$$
must have units of velocity.  Whatever the units of the coordinate $q$ are, they'll  cancel out; an extra dot at your arrow would give you too many factors of time  in the denominator.

This is rather cryptic restatement of the [chain rule for total derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule), which is
$$
\frac d{dt} x(a,b,\cdots,t) 
= \frac{\partial x}{\partial a} \frac{d a}{d t}
+ \frac{\partial x}{\partial b} \frac{d b}{d t}
+ \cdots
+ \frac{\partial x}{\partial t}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Now I understand. I didn't notice the dot on the $\dot {q_j}$. Euler's theorem will give us the correct result:

[image]