# Gauge invariance of Lagrangian with $\dot{q}_i$

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism

This question is related to
[Lagrangian gauge invariance](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/405873/lagrangian-gauge-invariance-l-l-fracdfq-tdt?rq=1) and [Adding a total time derivative term to the Lagrangian](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/174137/adding-a-total-time-derivative-term-to-the-lagrangian) but now what if the function $F = F(\{q_i\}, \{\dot{q}_i\},t)$? Will the Lagrangian $L' = L + dF/dt$ still yield the same Euler-Lagrange equations?

My gut instinct says no, but I am not sure how to prove/show this. For the total differential of $F$ I get
$$dF = \frac{\partial F}{\partial t}dt + \frac{\partial F}{\partial q}dq + \frac{\partial F}{\partial \dot{q}}d\dot{q},$$
but when I try to perform the same procedure as those linked above, I don't believe I find the correct derivatives when plugging it into the Euler-Lagrange equations.

Any help or ideas is appreciated. I am not sure if I have to go back to the action and perform the variation there to find the root cause or what. I know there are second-order Euler-Lagrange equations, but I don't think this is hinting at that.

For example, when I evaluate $\frac{\partial}{\partial\dot{q}}\left(\frac{dF}{dt}\right)$, I find that the $\partial F/\partial t$ term goes away, but I am left with
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial\dot{q}} + \frac{\partial}{\partial \dot{q}}\left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial\dot{q}}\ddot{q}\right)$$,
which I do not know how to evaluate the last term, or just get rid of the second order derivative since no $\dot{q}$s are present. This may be trivial and I am over thinking. If it does go away, then I will be left with the same result when $\dot{q}$ is not present in $F$.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/112036/2451 and links therein.

Comment: @Qmechanic The possible duplicate link explains why, but doesn't really show why it is true that you still get the $\textit{same}$ Euler-Lagrange equations when adding a term $F = F(q,\dot{q},t)$. I really just need a hint on whether or not I should start by plugging in directly the new $L$ into the Euler-Lagrange equations, or start from Hamilton's principle, and compute the variation and argue what needs to go to zero at the boundary.

Comment: @Qmechanic I just edited it to show where I am specifically stuck.

Comment: There are more terms. One should e.g. also differentiate wrt. $\ddot{q}$.