Understanding gauge in Lagrangian mechanics
I know given a Lagrangian $\mathcal{L}$ satisfying the Euler-Lagrange equations, then the Lagrangian $\mathcal{L}'=\mathcal{L}+\frac{d}{dt}f(q,t)$ is also a solution of said equations. Nonetheless, I keep getting that not every function of this form can be added to the original Lagrangian. Introducing $\mathcal{L}'$ in the Euler-Lagrange equations:
$$\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}'}{\partial q}-\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}'}{\partial \dot q}\right)=\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial q}-\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot q}\right)+\frac{\partial}{\partial q}\frac{d}{dt}f(q,t)-\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial }{\partial \dot q}\frac{d}{dt}f(q,t)$$
The first two terms on the right hand side add up to zero since we established $\mathcal{L}$ is a solution, and since we know $\mathcal L'$ is also a solution, then this equality must also be zero. Hence:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial q}\frac{d}{dt}f(q,t)-\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial }{\partial \dot q}\frac{d}{dt}f(q,t)=0$$
Rearranging the operators, I end up with:
$$\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial q}-\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial}{\partial\dot q}\right)\frac{df}{dt}=0$$
Which is zero in the case of the Lagrangian, but I'm not sure how this is also guaranteed to be zero for any arbitrary $f(q,t)$.

Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/405873/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/174137/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/112036/2451 and links therein.

You are almost there. You just need to expand the equation.
$$\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial q} - \frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial}{\partial\dot{q}} \right)\frac{d f(q,t)}{dt} = 0
$$
Continuing, we get that
\begin{split}
\frac{\partial}{\partial q}\frac{d f(q,t)}{dt} &= \frac{\partial}{\partial q} \left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial q} \dot{q}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} \right) \\
\end{split}
and similarly,
\begin{split}
\frac{d}{dt}\left( \frac{\partial}{\partial \dot{q}}\frac{d f(q,t)}{dt} \right) &= \frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial \dot{q}} \left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial q} \dot{q}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} \right)\right) \\
&= \frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial \dot{q}} \left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial q} \dot{q} \right)\right)\\
& = \frac{d}{dt}\left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial q} \right) \\
&= \dot{q}\frac{\partial}{\partial q}\frac{\partial f}{\partial q}+ \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\frac{\partial f}{\partial q}
\end{split}
Putting everything together, we have that
\begin{split}
\frac{\partial}{\partial q} \left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial q} \dot{q}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} \right) - \dot{q}\frac{\partial}{\partial q}\frac{\partial f}{\partial q}+ \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\frac{\partial f}{\partial q} &= 0
\end{split}
which clearly shows that
\begin{equation}
0 = 0.
\end{equation}
