When computing the Euler–Lagrange equations, why do we assume the coordinates do not depend on time?
I've just started to learn lagrangians through this video and I'm a bit confused. The setup has that $L = T-V$. With $T=\tfrac{1}{2}mv^2$ and $V=mgx$. So, $L= \tfrac{1}{2}m(dx/dt)^2-mgx$. This is all good. He then calcualtes $d/dt (dL/dv)-dL/dx$ which is where it gets confusing for me. He writes that $dL/dx = -mg$. But if we are differentiating with respect to $x$, which is really just a function of $t$, aren't we really differentiating with respect to $t$? But then this means that $T$ shouldn't reduce to $0$ right? There's an analagous case for $dL/dv$. I think I'm probably messing up the definition of a derivative or something but clarification on this matter will be great.

Please use MathJax to type formulae, as this makes the expressions more readable and will increase the chances of people taking the time to read your post.

This seems to mainly be a question about partial differentiation. See, for example, this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4898480/ Anyways, the upshot is that you need to treat the Lagrangian $L(x,v)$ as a function of two variables, $x$ and $v$, and assume no relation between $x$ and $v$. It is only when you calculate the action that you replace $v$ with $\dot x(t)$ a la: $S[x] = \int dt L(x(t), \dot x(t))$. The variation of the action gives the EL EOM, but you still have to remember your promise to treat L as a function of two variables...

Possible duplicates: Calculus of variations -- how does it make sense to vary the position and the velocity independently? and links therein.

Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/428990/174766

actually, it is not $dL/dx$ but $\partial L/\partial x$.  You are taking the partial derivative.

Consider a function $F$ of two variables $a$ and $b$:
$$
F(a,b)\;,
$$
where the usual notation of parentheses and a comma indicates that $F$ is a function of two independent variables, $a$ and $b$.
Consider, for concreteness, an explicit example such as:
$$
F(a, b) = a + b^2\;.
$$
We write the partial derivative with respect to the first independent variable as
$$
\frac{\partial F}{\partial a} = 1\;.
$$
We write the partial derivative with respect to the second independent variable as
$$
\frac{\partial F}{\partial b} = 2b\;.
$$

Nothing in the above discussion can stop me from evaluating the function $F(a,b)$ at the values $a=x(t)$ and $b=\dot x(t)$. Indeed, nothing can stop me from writing:
$$
F(x(t),\dot x(t)) = x(t) + \dot x(t)^2\;.
$$
If I would like, I can also proceed to consider the integral:
$$
G[x] = \int_{t_1}^{t_2} dt F(x(t), \dot x(t))\tag{1}\;,
$$
Setting the variation of the integral in Eq. (1), with respect to the path $x(t)$, equal to zero results in the equation:
$$
\left.\frac{\partial F}{\partial a}\right|_{a=x(t), b=\dot x(t)} - \frac{d}{dt}\left.\frac{\partial F}{\partial b}\right|_{a=x(t), b=\dot x(t)} = 0\;,\tag{2}
$$
which is the Euler Lagrange equation for this system.

To be even more explicit about the variation of $G$ with respect to the function $x(t)$, I will explicitly write:
$$
G[x+\epsilon w] = \int_{t_1}^{t_2} dt F(x(t)+\epsilon w(t), \dot x(t) +\epsilon \dot w(t))\;,\tag{3}
$$
where $\epsilon$ is a "small" constant and $w(t)$ is arbitrary function, other than being constrained by the condition that $w(t_1) = w(t_2) = 0$.
Expanding the RHS of Eq. (3) to first order in epsilon gives:
$$
G[x+\epsilon w] = G[x] + \epsilon\int_{t_1}^{t_2} dt \left(
w(t)\left.\frac{\partial F}{\partial a}\right|_{a=x(t), b=\dot x(t)}
+
\dot w(t)\left.\frac{\partial F}{\partial b}\right|_{a=x(t), b=\dot x(t)}
\right)
+O(\epsilon^2)
$$
$$
=G[x] + \epsilon\int_{t_1}^{t_2} dt w(t)\left(
\left.\frac{\partial F}{\partial a}\right|_{a=x(t), b=\dot x(t)}
-
\frac{d}{dt}\left.\frac{\partial F}{\partial b}\right|_{a=x(t), b=\dot x(t)}
\right)
+O(\epsilon^2)\;.
$$
Thus, the variational derivative of $G$ with respect to the curve $x(t)$ is zero when Eq. (2) above holds. And, as I already noted, Eq. (2) above is the Euler Lagrange equation for this system.

This is something I recently had to grapple with, so I hope I have this right.
The Euler-Lagrange formula is the general solution a path which extremizes an action (the integral of the Lagrangian).  If a physical system admits a Langrangian, then its solution is the Euler-Lagrange formula.  For the problems Lagrange was looking at, this is a natural sort of maximization problem.
William Hamilton later noticed that if you choose the Lagrangian $L=T-V$, then the resulting Euler-Lagrange formula is the 2nd order differential equation defined by Newtonian physics.  The fact that $x$ and $\dot x$ can vary independently is less of a physically meaningful statement, and more just the way a Newtonian physics problem looks when you rewrite it in the form of a stationary action.
And yes, its strange.  If I may quote an answer from the question Qmechanic linked, I can point out that you're not the first to find this to be strange, nor the last.  This is the forward from "Applied Differential Geometry". By William L. Burke


An essential aspect of calculus of variations is that $x$ and $\dot{x}$ cannot be varied independently; they are intrinsically connected. The purpose of the differentiation is to evaluate the contribution that each makes to the action. Comparison: let there be a fluid container with a uniform inflow, but the rate of outflow is proportional to how high the container is filled. At what height does the fluid content stop increasing? To calculate the answer: apply differentiation. There is a point where the rate of outflow matches the rate of inflow. At that point: derivative of net flow is zero

@Cleonis As I understood it (and please correct me if I'm wrong), the calculus of variations is structured around finding a path through a vector space of independent state variables, and thus the relationship between $x$ and $\dot x$ doesn't show up until you choose to use the Euler-Lagrange equation to reformulate an N-th order ODE into Lagrangian mechanics, and then there's a relationship.  Even then, the relationship is only on-shell, and some operations we do when leveraging the calculus of variations are intrinsicallly off-shell (tied to the mathematics, not the physics).

I suppose this is an area with room for interpretation. My perspective is to think of calculus of variations exclusively in terms of mathematics. Any physical case that I give serves only as motivating example. When I use mathematics to find the shape of a hanging chain then mathematically the unique solution already exists - but it is implicit. The problem is one of uncovering the solution; to render explicit. You use the metaphor doesn't-show-up-until, but as seen from my perspective even as a metaphor that is not a good fit.

Can I persuade you to contact me directly? (link to to a contact page on my website is available on my stackexchange profile page)  In this age of internet knowledge is more searcheable than ever. I have combed, and I believe that what I assembled has put me in a position to put pieces together that haven't been put together before. Other than that: I have seen it argued, such that it has convinced me, that calculus of variations is a subset of differential calculus. Things that used to look strange subsequently fell into place.

Quoting from your question:

But if we are differentiating with respect to x, which is really just a function of t, aren't we really differentiating with respect to t?

In my opinion the problem here is confusing notation.
In the case the exposition in the video that you link to (Michel van Biezen), here is the differentiation that actually accomplishes the goal:
with $h$ as height:
$$ \frac{d(\tfrac{1}{2}mv^2)}{dh} - \frac{d(-\int_{h_0}^h \ F \ dh)}{dh} \tag{1} $$
Here the symbol $h$ is used to represent height coordinate generically.
(As we know: potential energy is defined as the negative of the integral of Force with respect to height coordinate: $-\int_{h_0}^h \ F \ dh$ )
The differentiation of the Lagrangian is differentiation with respect to the direction of the variation, and in this case the direction of the variation is the vertical direction: the height.
In this case the potential energy is mass times gravitational acceleration times height.
with $V$ for the potential energy:
$$ V(h) = mgh \tag{2} $$
Hence:
$$ \frac{dV(h)}{dh} = mg \tag{3} $$
If in the above the symbol $x$ would be used instead of $h$ then there is risk of confusion, as sometimes plain $x$ is used as shorthand for $x(t)$, where $x$ is a function of $t$.




Returning to (1): I must explain this notation, of course:
$$ \frac{d(\tfrac{1}{2}mv^2)}{dh}  \tag{4} $$
In the following the left hand side is the same as (4), and the right hand side is the notation as used in the Euler-Lagrange equation:
$$ \frac{d(\tfrac{1}{2}mv^2)}{dh} \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad \frac{d}{dt}\frac{d(\tfrac{1}{2}mv^2)}{dv} \tag{5} $$
The above two differentiations are the same differentiation, what sets them apart is the order of operations.
To demonstrate (5):
Restating (4) in Leibniz notation, using $x$ for position coordinate:
$$ \frac{d(\tfrac{1}{2}m(\tfrac{dx}{dt})^2)}{dx} \tag{6} $$
Apply the chain rule, and write the result in Leibniz notation for the chain rule: a product of two differentations:
$$ \frac{d(\tfrac{dx}{dt})}{dx} \cdot \frac{d(\tfrac{1}{2}m(\tfrac{dx}{dt})^2)}{d(\tfrac{dx}{dt})} \tag{7} $$
The differentiation operator can be collapsed:
$$ \frac{d(\tfrac{dx}{dt})}{dx} \Rightarrow \frac{d}{dt} \tag{8} $$
Then (7) can be restated as follows:
$$ \frac{d}{dt} \frac{d(\tfrac{1}{2}m(\tfrac{dx}{dt})^2)}{d(\tfrac{dx}{dt})} \tag{9} $$
Which is according to the term for the kinetic energy in the Euler-Lagrange equation.
$$ \frac{d}{dt} \frac{d(\tfrac{1}{2}mv^2)}{dv} \tag{10} $$

This way of demonstrating (5) is abuse of notation, of course. It's a shortcut for sure, but the relation itself is correct.
Returning to the first notation:
$$ \frac{d(\tfrac{1}{2}mv^2)}{dh} - \frac{d(-\int_{h_0}^h \ F \ dh)}{dh} \tag{11} $$
The point is: the two energies, kinetic and potential, must be subjected to the same differentiating operation.

Potential energy and kinetic energy both have dimensions of length squared divided by time squared: $L^2/T^2$
Force and acceleration both have dimensions of length divided by time squared: $L/T^2$

The length dimension corresponds to the position coordinate. So, in order for the respective terms in the equation to remain dimensionally the same both energies must be differentiated with respect to the position coordinate.
