# Generalized Coordinates Property for a System of Particles

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, coordinate-systems, differentiation

I"m looking at "Principles of Dynamics: Second Edition" by Donald T Greenwood. I'm trying to figure out how he obtains Eq. (6-64)

$$\frac{\partial\dot x_j}{\partial\dot q_i} = \frac{\partial x_j}{\partial q_i}\tag{6-64}$$

from Eq (6-54)

$$\dot x_j = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial x_j}{\partial q_i}\dot q_i + \frac{\partial x_j}{\partial t}.\tag{6-54}$$

where the transformation equations from a set of $3N$ Cartesian coordinates to a set of $n$ generalized coordinates are of the form given by Eq (6-1)

$$x_1=f_1(q_1,q_2,...,q_n,t)$$
$$x_2=f_2(q_1,q_2,...,q_n,t)$$
$$\vdots$$
$$x_{3N}=f_{3N}(q_1,q_2,...,q_n,t).\tag{6-1}$$

When I differentiate Eq (6-54) with respect to $q_i$ I get second derivatives and I have no idea how the term $\frac{\partial^2 x_j}{\partial t\partial \dot q_i}$ is dealt with. Any insight appreciated.

Comment: You can find an answer here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/15037/why-does-cancellation-of-dots-frac-partial-dot-mathbfr-i-partial-dot

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with Greenwood, but I think any text addressing Hamiltonian Mechanics with proof will answer the question. Here's a standard introductory text:https://www.amazon.com/Classical-Dynamics-Particles-Systems-Thornton/dp/0534408966/ref=sr_1_2?keywords=physics+particles+and+systems&qid=1560530493&s=gateway&sr=8-2

Comment: Thank you both for the references and sorry for the duplicate question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Greenwood  is asking how does  $\dot x_j$ change if we vary  $\dot q_i$ at some specified time $t$ and point  $q_i$ (or equivalantly a specified point  $x_i$ as there is a - perhaps time dependent -  1-1 relation between the $q$'s and $x$'s). At that specified point and time  all the quantities on the RHS of your second equation, with the exception of the $\dot q$'s are to be treated as  constants. The answer then, is exactly your first equation.

Comment: Ahhhhh, I think I see now. Just to clarify, $\frac{\partial\dot q_i}{\partial \dot q_j}=0 $, because $q_i$ is independent of $q_j$ for $i \ne j$?

Comment: Yes. You can vary the $\dot \q_i$'s independently of one another.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks again!!