# D'Alembert's principle derivation in Goldstein's Classical Mechanics book

Tags: classical-mechanics, coordinate-systems, velocity, differentiation

(I could not find any answer to the following question in other related questions posted on SE, so asking it here.)

In the derivation of D'Alembert's principle in his ["book"](https://detritus.fundacioace.com/pub/books/Classical_Mechanics_Goldstein_3ed.pdf), Goldstein uses the relation,

[image]

Where the set {ri} is the set of cartesian coordinates used to describe the configuration of a given system and {qi} is the set of independent coordinates such that each ri can be expressed in terms of qi's.
i.e. ri=ri(q1,q2,.......,t) where 't' is time. vi is given by the equation,

[image]

Now, my question is how is the expression (1.51)(given in the first image) obtained? I tried to directly differentiate the expression of vi, but it will give another term on the RHS of (1.51). 
I tried to find out on google, and I got ["this"](https://web.stanford.edu/class/me331b/documents/InterchangePropertyOfPartialAndOrdinaryDerivative.pdf) pdf which also agrees with my doubt.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/15037/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variables $q$ and $\dot q$ are assumed to be independent, as they are the coordinates of the tangent bundle to the $q$-space (the so-called *configuration space*). Therefore, in the expression for $v$, take the partial derivative w.r.t the $\dot q$s, keeping the $q$s fixed. You can see that $v$ is linear in the $\dot q$s, therefore that partial derivative gives you a Kronecker delta inside the summation.