# How to determine the Lagrangian's "true" explicit dependence on time?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, time, symmetry, action

If your Lagrangian satisfies

$$
\frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial t} = 0
$$

then you're happy, energy is conserved, etc. However, if the above doesn't hold, that doesn't necessarily mean energy isn't conserved; maybe your Lagrangian has a false explicit time dependency. For example:

$$
\mathcal L = \frac{m}{2}\dot x^2+kt\dot x
$$

The above Lagrangian has $\partial \mathcal L/\partial t = k\dot x $ but I call that dependency fake (or as the experts like to say, "spurious") because it has the same equations of motion as this other Lagrangian:

$$
\mathcal L = \frac{m}{2}\dot x^2-kx
$$

which has no explicit time dependency whatsoever, so energy *is* conserved. Specifically, this happened because you can shift derivatives around in your Lagrangian using integration by parts at the level of the action.

Similarly, the following Lagrangian

$$
\mathcal L = \frac{m}{2}\dot x^2+gt
$$

also has a fake explicit time dependency, since you can remove $gt$ which is just a total time derivative, equivalent to a boundary term in the action.

On the other hand, the Lagrangian with variable mass

$$
\mathcal L = \frac{m(t)}{2}\dot x^2
$$

is bonafide explicit time-dependent. There's no trick here to avoid it; $\partial \mathcal L/\partial t \ne 0$ no matter what legal modifications you perform.

Finally, the following Lagrangian has a mixture of real and false explicit time-dependencies:

$$
\mathcal L = \frac{m(t)}{2}\dot x^2 -kx +gt
$$

Its true explicit time dependency would be defined as $\partial \mathcal L/\partial t$ *after* all integration by parts that could be performed have been done so and all total derivatives have been removed. Therefore, the question is:

**Given a generic Lagrangian, can its true explicit time dependency be determined in general?**

Comment: Comment to the post (v2): Are we allowed to make time-reparametrizations, i.e. to reparametrize time $t^{\prime}=f(t)$? If yes, then the time-varying mass $m(t)$ could also be fake.

Comment: @Qmechanic Time is absolute in the examples I gave, so I wouldn't say you have the right to reparametrize it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The third Lagrangian differs from the standard free Lagrangian just by a total derivative so that it produces the same equation of motion. This leads you to the answer.

You can ignore explicit temporal dependencies if they are due to an addend $\Delta L$  to $L$ which is a *formal total derivative*:
$$\Delta L = \frac{\partial g}{\partial t} +\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\partial g}{\partial q^k} \dot{q}^k$$
where $g= g(t,q)$.

So, if $\frac{\partial L}{\partial t} \neq 0$, but $\frac{\partial L - \Delta L}{\partial t} = 0$ for $\Delta L$ as above, you can ignore this dependence on time. More strongly you can re-define $L' = L -\Delta L$ which produces the same equations of motion and $\frac{\partial L'}{\partial t} = 0$.

This is the case also concerning the first couple of Lagrangians as their difference is a total derivative:
$$\frac{d }{dt}ktx\:.$$
Alternatively, and this is equivalent, you can  neglect the time dependence on time if the partial derivative of the Lagrangian is a total derivative. This follows from the argument above if noticing that the total derivative operator and the partial derivative operator commute on functions of $q $ and $t $.

Answer (score 4):

1. OP seems to ponder how to reliably check whether a term $\Delta L$ in the Lagrangian
   $$ \tilde{L}(q,\dot{q},t)~=~ L(q,\dot{q},t)+ \Delta L(q,\dot{q},t) \tag{1}$$ 
   is (perhaps secretly?) a total-derivative term or not? (Say, in complicated situations with many degrees of freedom.) Well, a fool-proof test (that doesn't rely on clever rewritings) is the following: *The term $\Delta L$ is a total derivative if$^{~1}$ and only if the Euler-Lagrange (EL) operator annihilates $\Delta L$ identically$^2$*
   $$ \frac{\partial \Delta L}{\partial q^j} -\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt} \frac{\partial \Delta L}{\partial \dot{q}^j}~=~0. \tag{2}$$ 
   This strategy was e.g. used in my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/23123/2451). See also [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/22249/2451) related Phys.SE post.
2. It is true the [Euler-Lagrange (EL) equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation) do not change when we change the Lagrangian with a total time derivative
   $$ \tilde{L}~=~ L+ \frac{\mathrm dF}{\mathrm dt}, \tag{3}$$ 
   cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/174137/2451) and [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/87628/2451) Phys.SE posts.
   However, we stress that the pertinent boundary conditions (BCs) of the variational problem might get affected by the change (3), cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/112036/2451) and [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/218843/2451) Phys.SE posts.

References:

1. G. Barnich, F. Brandt and  M. Henneaux, *Local BRST cohomology in gauge theories,* Phys. Rep. 338 (2000) 439, [arXiv:hep-th/0002245](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0002245).

--

$^1$ The "if"-part assumes that the configuration space is contractible, cf. an algebraic Poincare lemma of the so-called bi-variational complex, see e.g. Ref. 1. For non-contractible configuration spaces there could in principle be topological obstructions.

$^2$ This statement can be generalized/modified to accommodate local field theories with higher-order derivatives.

Comment: +1 against my own answer! Regarding your 2nd comment: I think that boundary conditions matter only if $F$ includes $\dot{q}$. I have excluded this fact in my answer. This is because it is difficult to interpret things like $\ddot{q}$ in the geometrical setting of standard Lagrangian mechanics where the relevant space is a jet-bundle of order $1$.

Comment: Also the condition $ \frac{\partial \Delta L}{\partial q^j} -\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt} \frac{\partial \Delta L}{\partial \dot{q}^j}~=~0$ is difficult to rigorously  understand for me, since performing computations when  $\Delta L$ is function of $t,q$ AND $\dot{q}$, I face a term of the form $d\dot{q}/dt $ which,  "off shell",  has no meaning since the only variables I am supposing to be independent off shell are $q$ and $\dot{q}$. It is clear that your statement is morally true ($q$-in simply connected regions) as it follows by direct inspection...

Comment: However to state it into a rigorous form I should use a space where $\ddot{q}$ has an off-shell meaning and this is not the standard space of classical analytical mechanics which is $J^1(V^{n+1})$, where $V^{n+1}$ is the spacetime of configurations (a fiber bundle with basis given by  the temporal axis $\mathbb R^2$ and fibers given by the $n$-dimensional configuration spaces $Q^n_t$ at fixed time.)

Comment: I prefer $J^1(V^{n+1})$ in place of $TQ \times \mathbb R$ because the second version (the most common) of the spacetime of kinetic states uses a decomposition which is not natural. If it were, conditions like $\partial_t L =0$ would be universal (independent from any possible coordinate system over   the spacetime of kinetic states)  and they are not.