Something fishy with canonical momentum fixed at boundary in classical action
There's something fishy that I don't get clearly with the action principle of classical mechanics, and the endpoints that need to be fixed (boundary conditions).  Please, take note that I'm not interested in answers with the hamiltonian, which isn't the point here.  I want to stay within the Lagrangian formalism.  Suppose we have a general Lagrangian $L(q, \dot{q},t)$, with standard action
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
  S[q] = \int_{t_1}^{t_2} L(q, \dot{q},t) \, dt.
 \end{equation}
If I vary this action in the usual way with Dirichlet boundary conditions $\delta q^i(t_1) = \delta q^i(t_2) = 0$, then I get the usual Euler-Lagrange (EL) equations as is usually shown everywhere.  This is all nice.  But now I want to let the variations $\delta q^i$ to stay arbitrary at the boundary, but fix the canonical momentum
$$ p_i(q,\dot{q},t)~:=~\frac{\partial L(q,\dot{q},t)}{\partial\dot{q}^i} $$
instead: $\delta p_i(t_1) = \delta p_i(t_2) = 0$.  In this case, varying (1) can't give back the EL equations:
\begin{align}
  \delta S &= \int_{t_1}^{t_2} \biggl( \frac{\partial L}{\partial q^i} \: \delta q^i - \frac{d}{dt} \Bigl( \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}^i} \Bigr) \delta q^i + \frac{d}{dt} \Bigl( \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}^i} \: \delta q^i \Bigr) \biggr) dt \\
  &= \int_{t_1}^{t_2} \biggl( \frac{\partial L}{\partial q^i} - \frac{d }{d t} \Bigl( \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}^i} \Bigr) \biggr) \delta q^i \, dt + p_i \, \delta q^i \Bigr|_{t_1}^{t_2}. \tag{2}
 \end{align}
Since $\delta q^i \ne 0$ at $t_1$ and $t_2$ (and in general $p_i \ne 0$ at the boundary), the last term doesn't cancel and we can't get the EL equations.  If I really want to impose $\delta p_i(t_1) = \delta p_i(t_2) = 0$ (not $p_i(t_1) = p_i(t_2) = 0$ !), then I need to modify the Lagrangian.  We're allowed to add a total time derivative:
\begin{equation}\tag{3}
  \tilde{L} = L + \frac{dQ}{dt},
 \end{equation}
where $Q(q, \dot{q}, t)$ must be chosen wisely.  In this case:
\begin{equation}\tag{4}
  \tilde{S} =  \int_{t_1}^{t_2} \tilde{L} \, dt = \int_{t_1}^{t_2} L \, dt + Q \Bigr|_{t_1}^{t_2}.
 \end{equation}
But then, this is where I feel confused.  If I use
\begin{equation}\tag{5}
  Q(q, \dot{q}, t) = - q^i \, p_i,
 \end{equation}
where $p_i = \partial L / \partial \dot{q}^i = p_i(q, \dot{q})$ is the canonical momentum from the "old" Lagrangian $L$, then the "new" lagrangian (3) have second order terms, i.e $\ddot{q}^i$ (from the total time derivative and $\dot{p}_i$).  I don't think this really gives an issue since these second order terms are coming in a special way, i.e from a total time derivative.  Varying the "new" action (4) give
\begin{align}
  \delta\tilde{S} &= \int_{t_1}^{t_2} \biggl( \frac{\partial L}{\partial q^i} - \frac{d }{d t} \Bigl( \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}^i} \Bigr) \biggr) \delta q^i \, dt + p_i \, \delta q^i \Bigr|_{t_1}^{t_2} - (p_i \, \delta q^i + q^i \, \delta p_i ) \Bigr|_{t_1}^{t_2} \\
  &= \int_{t_1}^{t_2} \biggl( \frac{\partial L}{\partial q^i} - \frac{d }{d t} \Bigl( \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}^i} \Bigr) \biggr) \delta q^i \, dt - q^i \, \delta p_i \Bigr|_{t_1}^{t_2}, \tag{6}
 \end{align}
which is the desired result to use the boundary conditions $\delta p_i(t_1) = \delta p_i(t_2) = 0$ and get back the EL equations from the "old" Lagrangian.
So what is wrong with this?  Why am I confused here?  Is there something important that I'm missing?  I tried to find something about this is Goldstein's book on Classical Mechanics, and also in Classical Dynamics by José-Saletan, but didn't found anything.  I guess that if the procedure above was valid, then it would have been described in these books and elsewhere!  So something must be wrong in the procedure above.
EDIT: I'm perplexed by the possibility that the imposed conditions may be incompatible with the Lagrangian or the equations of motions (EOM), without knowing the EOM in advance.  For example, it's possible that the imposed positions $q_1^i$ at time $t_1$ and $q_2^i$ at time $t_2$ may be incompatible with the general solution to the EOM, so that we may need to use the momentum instead (or other conditions).  Of course, the reverse is also true (incompatible momentum conditions, so need to use the coordinates instead).  I don't remember that I saw this discussed before.
EDIT 2: The following arXiv paper confirms that the procedure shown above is right: https://arxiv.org/abs/0809.4033.  In particular, from pages 15-17:
The bulk equations of motion are always unaffected by adding a total derivative, even one that contains higher derivatives of the fields. However, the addition of a total derivative may render the variational problem inconsistent, or require different boundary data in order to remain well-posed.
...
As a general rule of thumb, if an action contains higher derivatives which appear only as total derivatives, a boundary term will need to be added.

If we want to fix $p_i$ in the boundary conditions, it seems more natural to introduce the set ${ q_i , p_i }$ as independent variables. This will lead to the 1st order formalism or the Hamiltonian formalism you're not interested in.

@DexterKim, I'm not interested in the hamiltonian answer because I already know in details how it's working there.  In this case, you need to fix both the $q^i$ and the $p_i$ at the endpoints.  My point is you don't need to fix the coordinates at $t_1$ and $t_2$ to get back the EL equations.  You may fix the momentum alone at the endpoints, by using a modified lagrangian.

Normally one studies

weak essential/Dirichlet BC $\quad q(t_i)~=~q_i\quad\text{and}\quad q(t_f)~=~q_f,$

strong essential/Dirichlet BC $\quad q(t_i)~=~0\quad\text{and}\quad q(t_f)~=~0,$

strong natural BC: $\quad p(t_i)~=~0\quad\text{and}\quad p(t_f)~=~0,$

combinations thereof,


cf. e.g. my related Phys.SE answer here.
OP wants to study

weak natural BC: $\quad p(t_i)~=~p_i\quad\text{and}\quad p(t_f)~=~p_f.$

OP correctly adds boundary terms to the action so that the variational principle works. The only fishy parts seem to be that

the boundary terms look non-geometric, and

if there is any actual situation in Nature where a weak natural BC is required.




Can we say that the "weak natural BC" is a Neumann condition ?  2. And do you agree that my procedure is valid?



In this context the Neumann BC fixes the velocity rather than the momentum, which needs not be the same.


I agree that the momentum and the velocity are different (in general).  What about Robin conditions, which is a mix of Dirichlet and Neumann?  Can we say that your "weak natural BC" is a Robin condition?

The Robin BC is linear in $q$ and $\dot{q}$, while the weak natural BC could be non-linear.

Ok, thanks.  One last thing:  do you agree that the procedure that I exposed is valid and that the variationnal problem is well posed, if we want to fix the momentum on the boundary?  If so, then why it isn't shown in the standard textbooks?

I've edited the question.  I think I now understand better why I'm perplexed.  I need a reference that discuss the possibility that the coordinates condition may be incompatible with the EOM.  A simple example could be great to show that $q^i(t_1) = q_1^i$ and $q^i(t_2) = q_2^i$ may be incompatible with the Lagrangian, so we may need to use the momentum condition instead (or other conditions).

Given an action (modulo possible unspecified boundary terms), weak essential/Dirichlet BC could be incompatible with the actual physical BC (dictated by the physical system/situation), but not with the EL equations themselves per se.

Can you give a simple but non-trivial example showing that the usual $q(t_1) = q_1$ and $q(t_2) = q_2$ could be incompatible with the Lagrangian used, and that other conditions would be preferable?

It is often not the action per se but rather the physical situation. Think e.g. on a string with a free end.

I think part of the issue is notation, so let's write $\dot{q}$ as $v$. The Lagrangian is a function $L(q,v,t)$, where $q, v, t$ are independent variables. The principle of least action says that the path $t\mapsto q(t)$ minimises the functional
$$
S[q] = \int_{t_1}^{t_2}L(q(t),\dot{q}(t),t)\,dt.
$$
Now when you say you add a time derivative to $L$, i.e. $L'=L+\frac{dQ}{dt}$, what's really meant is that you are adding a function to $L$ of the form
$$\tag{*}
L'(q,v,t) = L(q,v,t)+\frac{\partial Q}{\partial q}(q,t)\,v+\frac{\partial Q}{\partial t}(q,t),
$$
where $Q(q,t)$ is any function. Then the action gets replaced by
$$
S'[q] = \int_{t_1}^{t_2}\left[L(q(t),\dot{q}(t),t)+\frac{\partial Q}{\partial q}(q(t),t)\,\dot{q}(t)+\frac{\partial Q}{\partial t}(q(t),t)\ \right] \, dt \\ = \int_{t_1}^{t_2}\left[L(q(t),\dot{q}(t),t)+\frac{d}{dt}Q(q(t),t) \right]\,dt = \int_{t_1}^{t_2}L(q(t),\dot{q}(t),t)\,dt + Q(q(t),t)\big\vert_{t_1}^{t_2},
$$
using the chain rule in the second step.
Hopefully it's now clear what's going wrong with your example. You're attempting to add $\frac{dQ}{dt}$, where now $Q(q,v,t)$. But this doesn't correspond to any equivalent of (*), since one would now need $L'$ to also depend on a new variable $a$ (or in original notation, $\ddot{q}$).
You've alluded to this in your original answer by saying "I don't think this really gives an issue since these second order terms are coming in a special way, i.e from a total time derivative." In fact, it does, and you would need to work with the EL-equations for Lagrangians of the form $L(q,\dot{q},\ddot{q},t)$ in order to make sense of what you are doing.

Your answer doesn't address the issue.  The term that is added to the Lagrangian is a "boundary" term which isn't a standard $Q(q, t)$.  While it seems to give $\tilde{L}(q, \dot{q}, \ddot{q})$ (superficially), it doesn't since the second order terms are removed under the standard variation (see equation (6)).

I'm pointing out that what you're doing doesn't in fact make any sense, since it doesn't define a new Lagrangian $L'(q,\dot{q},t)$. So variations of $S'[q]$ are not well-defined, unless you consider variations of more general Lagrangians $L(q,\dot{q},\ddot{q},t)$. And obviously the Euler-Lagrange equations for the latter will be different than the standard ones.

The added term is trivially canceling in the third order EL equation that we get from a general $L(q, \dot{q}, \ddot{q}, t)$, so we're back to the original second order EL equation!  And your answer appears to be in conflict with Qmechanics's.

The third order EL equations are $\frac{d^2}{dt^2}\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \ddot{q}}\right) - \frac{d}{dt}\left( \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}}\right) + \frac{\partial L}{\partial q} = 0$, so I don't know what you mean when you say the added term is cancelling in this to get back the second order EL equations. The boundary terms in this case become more complicated (they're no longer just $p_i\delta q^i$).

I disagree with Qmechanic's statement that "OP correctly add boundary terms to the action, so that the variational principle works". If you're unconvinced, just consider the trivial case $L=\frac{1}{2}m\dot{q}^2$. Are there any solutions of the EL-equations with $p(t_1) = 0, p(t_2)=1$, say?

I give up - suit yourself.

The issue is that the act of making the momentum a valid first-order dynamical variable is the Hamiltonian formalism; you will see this if you compare the process of moving to the Hamiltonian with that of swapping out energy with enthalpy or entropy with potentials in statistical mechanics.

Without that, yes, you will have a second order term and will need to use the general functional derivative. In the same way that carelessly treating a derivative like an algebraic fraction will easily lead to to inconsistencies, treating a functional differential equation like a normal one will also lead to inconsistencies.

@linkhyrule5, the point is it's not an inconsistency (or I don't see any).  The process is simple (please, if you see an inconsistency, give a complete answer as to why it's inconsistent):  You have a Lagrangian $L$ and seek its equations of motion without assuming $\delta q = 0$ at endpoints, but using $\delta p = 0$ instead.  You add a time derivative (even if it implies a $\ddot{q}$ from it, who cares?), then do the usual path variation to get the EL (it would be the third order EL if you assumed $\delta q_1 = \delta q_2 = 0$).  Then, you do get the usual EL!  So where's the inconsistency?

I've found a document that state that the procedure shown above is right: https://arxiv.org/abs/0809.4033.  In particular, on page 15-17:
The bulk equations of motion are always unaffected by adding a total derivative, even one that contains higher derivatives of the fields. However, the addition of a total derivative may render the variational problem inconsistent, or require different boundary data in order to remain well-posed.
...
As a general rule of thumb, if an action contains higher derivatives which appear only as total derivatives, a boundary term will need to be added.

I don't know if you're directing your comment at me, but looking at that paper, in their main toy example (taking $L_1 = \frac{1}{2}\dot{q}^2$ and adding an additional term $L_2 = -\frac{1}{2}q\ddot{q}$), they claim they're adding a total derivative, but clearly $L_2$ is not, so it's not even clear to me what point they're trying to make. Yes, the EL-equations in this case become second order, essentially since the leading term $L_2$ is linear in $\ddot{q}$.

In general, the variation for an action involving $L(q, \dot{q}, \ddot{q},t)$ will have a boundary term $\left[ \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}} \delta q + \frac{\partial L}{\partial \ddot{q}} \delta \dot{q} - \frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \ddot{q}} \right)\delta q\right]_{t_1}^{t_2}$, and the last two terms reduce to their BC. This would need to vanish to derive the third order EL equation, so this determines what the allowable BCs are. Maybe there's some way to formulate things so what you're saying makes sense, but I'm not seeing it from what you've written.

The point is that the total time derivative involved here (i.e $dQ/dt$ with $Q = - q^i p_i$) is "special", in that it let us change the boundary conditions from $\delta q = 0$ to $\delta p = 0$, even if $dQ/dt$ involves second order terms.  The variation shows that we don't need to use the third order EL equation.  We just get back to the standard second order EL equations, as usual.  There is no inconsistency in that case.

If you want to believe that, knock yourself out. But as far as I can see, nothing in the paper actually supports your assertion. I would recommend you give a clear formulation of what you're asking, and post it as a new question.

Why are you so hard headed?  Just think anew, and try it yourself, it's easy.  Just take any lagrangian $L(q, \dot{q}, t)$ and add $dQ/dt$ with $Q(q, \dot{q}) = - q^i p_i$, then do the coordinates variation.  You'll see that you will need $\delta p_i = 0$ at $t_1$ and $t_2$ (without $\delta q^i = 0$) and get back the EL equations for the lagrangian $L$.  That's all. Apparently, you're so much hard minded that you don't want to learn something new.

I don't see this, and I've tried multiple times to explain to you why I don't see it, and why your analysis of it makes no sense to me. You apparently do, however, so what further can I say?

If you don't see this, then obviously you're doing mistakes in your $\delta S$ variation.  Just inspect again my equation (6).

You may be interested in the question and answer of this question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/112036/when-can-we-add-a-total-time-derivative-of-fq-dotq-t-to-a-lagrangian/112040#112040

The answer you link is entirely consistent with what I've said above - note that there, adding a $\frac{d}{dt}f(q,\dot{q},t)$ requires the introduction of a Lagrangian $\tilde{L}(q,\dot{q},\ddot{q},t)$, the corresponding EL equations are precisely the ones I wrote above, and will require a set of BCs that I wrote explicitly above. So again, I'm not sure what point you're trying to illustrate by pointing this out.

The point that you persist in not understanding is that the procedure I've shown in my question is entirely consistent.  The total derivative $dQ/dt$ do solves trivially the third order EL equation so we're back to the ordinary second order EL equation for $L$.  Your answer does NOT answer the query at all, and you still persist in arguing that the procedure isn't consistent.  It is!  I suggest that you simply erase your answer.

I submit that the treatment that you produced amounts to a Rube Goldberg machine
In the case of application of Calculus of Variations: in order to obtain an equation of motion: introducing a variation space introduces degrees of freedom; the imposed conditions narrow things down to a single equation of motion.
General property of applying conditions: if the supplied conditions provide insufficient constraint the problem is underdetermined, if there are too many constraints you get conflict; the problem is overdetermined.
So: we supply conditions such that the problem has a uniquely determined solution. Here the unique solution consists of a single equation of motion.
The point is:
It is to be expected that there are more ways than one to supply conditions such that the problem has a uniquely determined solution.

In mathematics in general: any theorem can be proved in multiple ways.
A particularly vivid example of that is Pythagoras' theorem. The count of total number of independent proofs somewhat depends on what one counts as being different, but  it's in the hundreds.

Returning to application of calculus of variations in classical mechanics:
You express surprise at finding out there is another way of supplying conditions such that the solution to the problem is uniquely determined. I submit: what you found is what is expected.
Presumably there is no upper limit; I expect that it will always be possible to find more elaborate ways to supply the necessary constraints.
