# Proving invariance of Lagrange's equations under transformation of the form $L' = L + \dfrac{d}{dt}g(\mathbf{q},t)$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, boundary-terms

A problem in my classical mechanics textbook is stated as follows:

> Show that if the Lagrangian $L(\mathbf{q},\dot{\mathbf{q}},t)$ is modified to $L'$ by any transformation of the form
>   $$
> L' = L + \dfrac{d}{dt}g(\mathbf{q},t)
> $$
>   then Lagrange's equations remain unchanged.

I approched the problem as follows:
$$
\dfrac{d}{dt}\left(\dfrac{\partial L'}{\partial \dot{q}_j}\right)-\dfrac{\partial L'}{\partial q_j} =0
$$
Since $g(\mathbf{q},t)$ is independent of $\dot{\mathbf{q}}$, this becomes:
$$
\dfrac{d}{dt}\left(\dfrac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}_j}\right)-\dfrac{\partial}{\partial q_j}\left(L+\dfrac{d}{dt}g(\mathbf{q},t)\right) =0
$$
$$
\dfrac{d}{dt}\left(\dfrac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}_j}\right)-\dfrac{\partial L}{\partial q_j} = \dfrac{\partial}{\partial q_j}\left(\dfrac{d}{dt}g(\mathbf{q},t)\right)
$$
Which leaves us to prove that
$$
\dfrac{\partial}{\partial q_j}\left(\dfrac{d}{dt}g(\mathbf{q},t)\right) = 0
$$

However, I seem to be unable to prove this. Did I make a mistake, or do I just fail to see how this can be proven?

Comment: Take $g\left( \mathbf{q}, t \right) = q_1$. Is its time derivative independent of $\dot q_1$?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/112036/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/22249/2451 , and links therein.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that
\begin{equation}
\frac{dg}{dt} = \frac{\partial g}{\partial q}\dot{q}+\frac{\partial g}{\partial t} \, .
\end{equation}
Hence
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial L'}{\partial \dot{q}}\right)-\frac{\partial L'}{\partial q} &=& \frac{d}{dt}\left[\frac{\partial }{\partial \dot{q}}\left(L+\frac{\partial g}{\partial q}\dot{q}+\frac{\partial g}{\partial t}\right) \right]-\frac{\partial}{\partial q}\left(L+\frac{dg}{dt} \right)
\\
&=& \frac{d}{dt}\left[\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}} \right] -\frac{\partial L}{\partial q} +  \frac{d}{dt}\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial\dot{q}}\left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial q}\dot{q}\right) \right]  -\frac{\partial}{\partial q}\left(\frac{dg}{dt} \right)
\\
&=& \frac{d}{dt}\left[\frac{\partial L}{\partial\dot{q}} \right] -\frac{\partial L}{\partial q} +  \frac{d}{dt}\left[\frac{\partial g}{\partial q} \right]  -\frac{\partial}{\partial q}\left(\frac{dg}{dt}  \right) \, .
\end{eqnarray}

Convince yourself that the extra terms cancel each other.