# Why are $p$ and $q$ independent variables in Hamiltonian formalism?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, hamiltonian-formalism, constrained-dynamics, degrees-of-freedom

Let's say we have $(q, \dot{q})$ as the generalised coordinate and  generalised velocity. If we have a Lagrangian given by
$$L=Aq\dot{q}+Bq$$
where $A$ and $B$ are constants that give the right units to the Lagrangian, then the canonical momentum $p$ we use to perform the Legendre transformation to get the Hamiltonian is

$$p=\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}}=Aq.$$
But then $p$ and $q$ are not independent variables as
$$\frac{\partial p}{\partial q}=\frac{\partial}{\partial q} Aq=A\neq0.$$

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: It is a *singular* Lagrangian. See Qmechanic's answer to this question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/47847/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. OP's Lagrangian $$L(q,v,t)~=~Aqv+Bq\tag{1}$$ has EL equation $$B~\approx~ 0,\tag{2}$$ so the theory only has classical solutions if $B=0$. In the latter case, the Lagrangian is a total derivative, so the [Euler-Lagrange (EL) equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation) is trivially satisfied. Either way, OP's Lagrangian leads to a rather singular theory.
2. Concerning the corresponding Hamiltonian formulation, OP's Lagrangian is an example where the Legendre transformation is singular, i.e. we cannot invert the relation $$p~=~\frac{\partial L}{\partial v}~=~Aq\tag{3}$$
   to find $v$ as a function of $p$. Instead eq. (3) is a [primary constraint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primary_constraint), i.e. $q$ and $p$ are indeed not independent variables, and one would have to perform a Dirac-Bergmann analysis. A secondary constraint is eq. (2). The Hamiltonian becomes $$H~=~\lambda(p-Aq),\tag{4}$$
   where $\lambda$ is a Lagrange multiplier.
3. For regular Lagrangians, see e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/27830/2451) related Phys.SE post.