# Hamilton-Jacobi Equation

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, hamiltonian-formalism, action

In the Hamilton-Jacobi equation, we take the partial time derivative of the action.  But the action comes from integrating the Lagrangian over time, so time seems to just be a dummy variable here and hence I do not understand how we can partial differentiate $S$ with respect to time?  A simple example would also be helpful.

Answer (score 24):

I) At least three different quantities in physics are customary called an action and denoted with the letter $S$.

1. The (off-shell) [action](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_%28physics%29)
   $$S[q]~:=~ \int_{t_i}^{t_f}\! dt \ L(q(t),\dot{q}(t),t) \tag{1}$$
   is a *functional* of the full position curve/path $q^i:[t_i,t_f] \to \mathbb{R}$ for *all* times $t$ in the interval $[t_i,t_f]$. See also [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/15325/2451) question. (Here the words *on-shell* and *off-shell* refer to whether the equations of motion (eom) are satisfied or not.)
2. If the [variational problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus_of_variations) $(1)$ with well-posed boundary conditions,
   e.g. Dirichlet boundary conditions
   $$ q(t_i)~=~q_i\quad\text{and}\quad q(t_f)~=~q_i,\tag{2}$$
   has a unique extremal/classical path $q_{\rm cl}^i:[t_i,t_f] \to \mathbb{R}$, it makes sense to define an on-shell action
   $$  S(q_f;t_f;q_i,t_i) ~:=~ S[q_{\rm cl}], \tag{3} $$
   which is a *function* of the boundary values. See e.g. [MTW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitation_%28book%29) Section 21.1.
3. The Hamilton's principal function $S(q,\alpha, t)$ in [Hamilton-Jacobi equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamilton%E2%80%93Jacobi_equation) is a *function* of the position coordinates $q^i$, integration constants $\alpha_i$, and time $t$, see e.g. H. Goldstein, *Classical Mechanics,* chapter 10.
   The total time derivative
   $$ \frac{dS}{dt}~=~ \dot{q}^i \frac{\partial S}{\partial q^i}+ \frac{\partial S}{\partial t}\tag{4}$$
   is equal to the Lagrangian $L$ on-shell, as explained [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamilton%E2%80%93Jacobi_equation#Action_and_Hamilton.27s_functions).
   As a consequence, the Hamilton's principal function $S(q,\alpha, t)$ can be interpreted as an action on-shell.

II) *Example: A non-relativistic free particle in 1 dimension.*

1. The off-shell action is
   $$ S[q]~=~  \frac{m}{2}\int_{t_i}^{t_f}\! dt \ \dot{q}(t)^2.\tag{5} $$
2. If we assume Dirichlet boundary conditions (2), the unique classical trajectory $q_{\rm cl}$ has constant velocity
   $$\dot{q}_{\rm cl}~=~\frac{q_f-q_i}{t_f-t_i}.\tag{6}$$
   The Dirichlet on-shell action (3) is
   $$  S(q_f,t_f;q_i,t_i) 
   ~=~ \frac{m}{2} \cdot \frac{(q_f-q_i)^2}{t_f-t_i}. \tag{7} $$
3. The Hamilton's principal function, i.e. a solution to Hamilton-Jacobi equation, is
   $$ S(q,E,t)~=~\pm\sqrt{2m E} q - Et,\tag{8} $$
   where $E$ is an integration constant (=the total energy). Due to the interpretation of Hamilton's principal function as a [type 2 generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_transformation#Type_2_generating_function) of [canonical transformations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_transformation), the partial derivative
   $$Q~:=~ \frac{\partial S}{ \partial E}~\stackrel{(8)}{=}~\pm\sqrt{\frac{m}{2E}}q -t \tag{9}$$
   must be a constant of motion. In other words, the position $q(t)$ is, as expected, an [affine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation) function of time $t$. This implies that the velocity is constant
   $$ \dot{q} ~\approx~\pm\sqrt{\frac{2E}{m}}, \tag{10}$$
   where the "$\approx$" symbol means equality modulo eom. The total time derivative of the Hamilton's principal function (8) is equal to the Lagrangian (=the kinetic energy) on-shell
   $$ \frac{dS}{dt}~\stackrel{(8)}{=}~ \pm\sqrt{2m E} \dot{q} -E ~\stackrel{(10)}{\approx}~E.\tag{11}$$
4. Let us now compare point 2 and 3. With the Dirichlet boundary conditions (2), the energy becomes
   $$  E~=~ \frac{m}{2} \cdot \left(\frac{q_f-q_i}{t_f-t_i}\right)^2. \tag{12}$$
   A comparison of eqs. (6) and (10) shows that we should use the plus (minus) branch of the solution (8) if $q_f\geq q_i$  ($q_f\leq q_i$), respectively.  It is straightforward to check that the difference in the Hamilton's principal function becomes the on-shell action (7),
   $$ \begin{align} S(q_f,E,t_f)~-~& S(q_i,E,t_i)\cr
   ~\stackrel{(8)+(12)}{=}&~\frac{m}{2} \cdot \frac{(q_f-q_i)^2}{t_f-t_i}\cr 
   ~\stackrel{(7)}{=}~~& S(q_f,t_f;q_i,t_i).\end{align}\tag{13} $$

Answer (score 21):

The action functional and Hamilton's principal function are two different mathematical objects related to the same physical quantity.

The action along a trajectory $\gamma:[t_1,t_2]\rightarrow Q$ is given by
$$
S[\gamma] = \int_{t_1}^{t_2}L(\gamma(t'),\dot\gamma(t'),t')dt'
$$
whereas the principal function is the solution of the Hamilton-Jacobi equation
$$
H(q,\nabla S(q,t),t) + \frac{\partial S}{\partial t}(q,t) = 0
$$

If you denote by $\gamma_{q,t}$ the solution of the Euler-Lagrange equations with
$$
\gamma_{q,t}(t_0)=q_0\\
\gamma_{q,t}(t)=q
$$
then
$$
S(q,t):=S[\gamma_{q,t}]=\int_{t_0}^{t}L(\gamma_{q,t}(t'),\dot\gamma_{q,t}(t'),t')dt'
$$
will solve the Hamilton-Jacobi equation.

On the flip side, for the principal function we have the following
$$
\frac{d}{dt}S(\gamma(t),t)=L(\gamma(t),\dot\gamma(t),t)
$$
and thus
$$
S[\gamma]=S(\gamma(t_2),t_2)-S(\gamma(t_1),t_1)
$$

Note that the last two equations only hold for trajectories with
$$
\frac{\partial L}{\partial\dot q}(\gamma(t),\dot\gamma(t),t) = \nabla S(\gamma(t),t)
$$

Geometrically, the choice of integration constants of the principal function selects a leaf of a foliation of phase space, which corresponds to the choice of initial condition $\gamma_q(t_0)=q_0$ from above.

Answer (score 6):

I think the other two answers are overkill. The simpler answer is that time $t$ is not a dummy variable. The integration of $L$ over time here is an indefinite integration, so if we have $L(q,\dot{q},t)$, and we want to integrate it over time $t$, the result is $$\int_{t_i}^tL(q,\dot{q},\tau)d\tau$$ here $\tau$ is the dummy variable but $t$ is not, and the result is a function of $t$.

Comment: I always thought of it this way.Variation of the above immediately gives the Hamilton-Jacobi equations.