# Variation of Action with time coordinate variations

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, variational-principle, action, boundary-terms

I was trying to derive equation (65) in the review by [László B. Szabados in *Living Reviews in Relativity* (2002, Article 4)](https://link.springer.com/article/10.12942/lrr-2004-4)

This slightly unusual then usual classical mechanics because it includes a variation of time also, $\delta t$.

Usually one would define,
$$\delta S~=~ \int \left[ L \left(\tilde{q}(t),\dot{\tilde{q}}(t),t\right) -  L \left(q(t),\dot{q}(t),t\right)\right] dt , $$
where,

$$\tilde{q}~=~q+\delta q. $$

We have then (before applying int by parts),

$$ \delta S ~=~ \int \left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial q}\delta q +\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot q}\delta \dot q\right)dt.$$

How does one proceed if both $q$ and $t$ vary and further that $q$ depends on a varying $t$?

Is the definition now

$$\delta S~=~ \int \left[ L \left(\tilde{q}(t+\delta t),\dot{\tilde{q}}( t+\delta t), t+\delta t\right) -  L \left(q(t),\dot{q}(t),t\right)\right] dt~?  $$

If so how does one proceed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I) Hint: Decompose the full infinitesimal variation

$$ \tag{A} \delta q~=~\delta_0 q + \dot{q} \delta t $$

in a vertical infinitesimal variation $\delta_0 q$ and a horizontal infinitesimal variation $\delta t$. Similarly the full infinitesimal variation becomes

$$ \tag{B} \delta I~=~\delta_0 I + \left[ L ~\delta t \right]_{t_1}^{t_2}, $$

where the vertical piece follows the standard [Euler-Lagrange](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation) argument

$$ \tag{C} \delta_0 I~=~ \int_{t_1}^{t_2}\! dt~\left[\frac{\partial L}{\partial q}-\dot{p} \right] \delta_0 q + \left[ p ~\delta_0q \right]_{t_1}^{t_2}, $$

and we have for convenience defined the Lagrangian momenta

$$ \tag{D} p~:=~\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}}. $$

Now combine eqs. (A-D) to derive eq. (65) in Ref. 1:

$$ \tag{65} \delta I~=~ \int_{t_1}^{t_2}\! dt~\left[\frac{\partial L}{\partial q}-\dot{p} \right] \delta_0 q + \left[ p ~\delta q - (p\dot{q}-L)\delta t\right]_{t_1}^{t_2}, $$

II) Ideologically, we should stress that Ref. 1 is *not* interested in proposing a variational principle for non-vertical variations (such as, e.g., [Maupertuis' principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maupertuis%27_principle), or a variant of Pontryagin's maximum principle, etc). Ref. 1 is merely calculating non-vertical variations within a theory that is still governed by the [principle of stationary action](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_action) (for vertical variations).

III) Ref. 1 mainly uses eq. (65) to deduce properties of the *on-shell Dirichlet action* $^1$

$$ \tag{E} S(q_2,t_2;q_1,t_1)~:=~I[q_{\rm cl};t_1,t_2],$$

cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/19847/2451) Phys.SE post.

References:

1. L.B. Szabados, *Quasi-Local Energy-Momentum and Angular Momentum in GR: A Review Article,*  [Living Rev. Relativity 7 (2004) 4](http://www.livingreviews.org/lrr-2004-4).

--

$^1$ Ref. 1 calls $S(q_2,t_2;q_1,t_1)$ the Hamilton-Jacobi principal function. Although related, the [Hamilton-Jacobi principal function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamilton%E2%80%93Jacobi_equation) $S(q,P,t)$ is strictly speaking another function, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/32268/2451) Phys.SE post.

Comment: Apologies if I'm overlooking something but shouldn't it be $\dot L \delta t$ ?

Comment: In which formula?

Comment: Ah forgot to specify but Equation B?

Comment: Ah sorry ignore me. That wouldn't even make dimensional sense.

Answer (score 9):

This is the **Variational Problem with free end-time** and one proceeds like this:

$$\delta S= \int_{t_i}^{t_f+\delta t_f} L \left(q+\delta q,\dot{q}+\delta \dot{q},t\right) dt - \int_{t_i}^{t_f} L \left(q, \dot{q}, t\right) dt$$

After several transformations and integration by parts one finally gets the usual [Euler-Lagrange diff eq](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation) plus a boundary condition involving $\delta t_f$:

$$0 = L(q, \dot{q}, t) \delta t_f + \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}}(\delta q_f - \dot{q} \delta t_f)$$

Derivation steps:

**a.** Expand the first integral in a Taylor series and keep terms of 1st order and splitting the limits of integration (and doing any cancelations):

$$
\delta S= 
\int_{t_f}^{t_f+\delta{t_f}} \left[ L + \frac{\partial{L}}{\partial{q}}\delta{q} + \frac{\partial{L}}{\partial{\dot{q}}}\delta{\dot{q}} \right] dt + 
\int_{t_i}^{t_f} \left[ \frac{\partial{L}}{\partial{q}}\delta{q} + \frac{\partial{L}}{\partial{\dot{q}}}\delta{\dot{q}} \right] dt 
$$

**b.** The total variation consists of 2 variations; $\delta{q}$ and $\delta{t_f}$. Integrating over a *small* interval i.e $[t_f, t_f + \delta{t_f}]$ is *effectively equivalent* to multiplication by $\delta{t_f}$:

$$
\delta S= 
\delta{t_f} \left[ L + \frac{\partial{L}}{\partial{q}}\delta{q} + \frac{\partial{L}}{\partial{\dot{q}}}\delta{\dot{q}} \right] + 
\int_{t_i}^{t_f} \left[ \frac{\partial{L}}{\partial{q}}\delta{q} + \frac{\partial{L}}{\partial{\dot{q}}}\delta{\dot{q}} \right] dt 
$$

**c.** Terms like $\delta{t_f}\delta{q}$ or $\delta{t_f}\delta{\dot{q}}$ are **2nd order** variations and can be dropped:

$$
\delta S= 
\delta{t_f} L + 
\int_{t_i}^{t_f} \left[ \frac{\partial{L}}{\partial{q}}\delta{q} + \frac{\partial{L}}{\partial{\dot{q}}}\delta{\dot{q}} \right] dt 
$$

**d.** Integration by parts yields a usual Euler-Lagrange diff eq. plus the boundary condition.

**e.** On the boundary condition at time $t_f$ one has:

Total variation  of $q$ at $t_f$ is

$$\delta{q_f} = \delta{q(t_f)} + (\dot{q} + \delta{\dot{q}})\delta{t_f} = \delta{q(t_f)} + \dot{q}\delta{t_f}$$

or

$$\delta{q(t_f)} = \delta{q_f} - \dot{q}\delta{t_f}$$

**Hint for @Y2H:**

The total variation at the boundary $\delta{q_f}$ is simply the sum of the path and time variations at the boundary (since these can be considered as independent variations), ie $(\delta{q(t_f)}) + (q(t_f+\delta{t_f})+\delta{q(t_f+\delta{t_f})}-q(t_f)-\delta{q(t_f)})$ and the latter can be decomposed (up to 1st order variations) as $(\dot{q}(t_f) + \delta{\dot{q}(t_f)})\delta{t_f}$

*PS: There has been a long time since posted this answer and I dont have my notes handy, but hope the above give you a hint.*

*PS2: Here are some synoptic [lecture notes on generalised calculus of variations with free end points](http://www.maths.adelaide.edu.au/matthew.roughan/notes/Variational_methods/files/lecture18.notes.pdf)*

Comment: Comment to the answer (v2): Note that to have a well-posed variational problem with unknown end-time, one in general needs to specify conditions on the allowed variations.

Comment: @Qmechanic, correct, the answer follows the question regarding the extended formalism, the conditions are part of the problem and the final time is related to the boundary condition

Comment: So is there a way to decompose that first integral?

Comment: @user50482, yes there is, these are taken mostly from my notes on optimal control theory (a-la Pontryagin), so did not put every derivation step, it is possible one can find online, else will have to look at the notes and add more steps of the derivation

Comment: @user50482, added derivation steps

Comment: @NikosM. Thanks! But I still fail to see how this reproduces the result in the OP, how would I get the $\dot{q} \delta t$ terms

Comment: Also if it helps the result in OP can be written as;

$$\int_{t1}^{t2} \left( \frac{\partial L}{\partial q}\delta q+
\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot q}\delta \dot q-
\frac{\partial L}{\partial q} \dot q \delta t- 
\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot q} \ddot q \delta t +
\frac{\partial L}{\partial t} \delta t \right) dt $$

Comment: @user50482, added derivation of boundary condition, the derivation of euler-lagrange is similar to the usual procedure (since all factors of variations should be identically zero)

Comment: @user50482, here is a more complete [review of calculus of variations](http://dml.cz/dmlcz/143142) (and slightly more rigorous), and a [list of applications](http://www.colorado.edu/ASEN/asen5227_offline/slides/292-334.pdf) that may be of help (regardless of accepting the answer or not) :)

Comment: @NikosM. could you please tell me how you arrived at $\delta q_{f}=\delta q\left(t_{f}\right)+(\dot{q}+\delta \dot{q}) \delta t_{f}$? I can’t get my head around this at all.

Comment: @Y2H, there has been a long time since posted this answer and I dont find my notes handy, but I will try to give you a hint. Updated my answer, hope it helps. For example Optimal Control theory makes heavy use of variational problems where many parameters are variated, including start and end time. Search for those to get the idea, although the derivations steps are given in this answer

Comment: @Y2H, found some synoptic but good [lecture notes on generalised calculus of variations with free end points](http://www.maths.adelaide.edu.au/matthew.roughan/notes/Variational_methods/files/lecture18.notes.pdf), To get you started

Comment: @NikosM. this seems helpful, I cannot thank you enough!!