# Variation of classical action due to variation of position and time

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, variational-principle, action

I am reading about the Brown-York formalism in https://link.springer.com/article/10.12942/lrr-2004-4. The document says that if we consider a deformation of our end points $(q,t$) in position and time, then the classical mechanics action varies by (equation (65) on p.76)

\begin{align}
        \nonumber \delta S^1[q^a(t)] := &\int_{t_1}^{t_2} \left( \frac{\partial L}{\partial q^a} - \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}^a} \right) (\delta q^a - \dot{q}^a \delta t) + \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}^a}\delta q^a\Big|_{t_1}^{t_2} \\
        &- \left( \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}^a} \dot{q}^a - L \right) \delta t\Big|_{t_1}^{t_2}.\tag{65}
    \end{align}

Could somebody tell me how we got to this?

Here’s what I’ve tried:

\begin{align}
    \delta S^1(q,\dot{q},t) = \frac{\partial S^1}{ \partial q} \delta q + \frac{\partial S^1}{ \partial \dot{q}} \delta \dot{q} + \frac{\partial S^1}{ \partial t} \delta t,\tag{a}
\end{align}

where the suppressed indices of the vectors $q$ and $\dot{q}$ are implied. The first term gives

$$\begin{equation}
    \frac{\partial S^1}{ \partial q} \delta q  = \int_{t_1}^{t_2} \frac{\partial L}{\partial q} \delta q \mathrm{d} t.
\end{equation}\tag{b}$$

The second term gives

$$\begin{align}
    \nonumber \frac{\partial S^1}{ \partial \dot{q}} \delta \dot{q} &= \int \frac{\partial S}{\partial \dot{q}} \delta \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} t} q \mathrm{d} t\\
    &= \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}} \delta q\Big|_{t_1}^{t_2} - \int \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} t} \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}} \delta q \mathrm{d} t.
\end{align}\tag{c}$$

To get to the last line I have used integration by parts. The third terms can be written as

$$\begin{align}
    \nonumber  \frac{\partial S^1}{ \partial t} \delta t &= \int_{t_1}^{t_2} L \mathrm{d}t \delta t \\
    \nonumber  &= L \delta t |_{t_1}^{t_2}\\
    &= \left( p^a \dot{q}_a - E \right) \delta t |_{t_1}^{t_2}.
\end{align}\tag{d}$$

The combination of the three terms leads to

$$\begin{align}
    \delta S^1 &= \int_{t_1}^{t_2} \left( \frac{\partial L}{\partial q} - \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}} \right) \left( \delta q + \dot{q} \delta t \right) + \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}}\delta q\Big|_{t_1}^{t_2} + (E + L)\delta t |_{t_1}^{t_2}.
\end{align}\tag{e}$$

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/119324/2451

Comment: @Qmechanic look at the answers in this question correctly, none of them really allows me to arrive at the above expression.

Comment: @Qmechanic in the ‘‘Best Answer’’ in that question, could you please explain to me how did $[L \delta t]_{t_1}^{t_2}$ in (B) become $p \delta q - p \dot{q}$ in (65)?

Comment: ${}$ It doesn't.

Comment: Concerning your post (v4): For starters, there are notational problems in eq. (a) since $S[q]$ is a functional not a function. Consider to fix that.

Comment: @Qmechanic is that single issue worth closing the question and depriving me from a much needed answer just because you like to play God?

Comment: Well, since the post was edit, it will now get a second opinion from other reviewers. To build your case, consider to include in the post why the duplicate doesn't answer your question.