# Hamilton-Jacobi Equation and uniform circular motion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, hamiltonian-formalism, action

I tried to apply Hamilton-Jacobi equation to uniform circular motion and it doesn't come out right.

Lets say a particle of mass $m$ undergoes uniform circular motion around another particle of mass $M$.

$$H=T+V = (1/2) m v^2 - GmM/r$$

$$S = \int{Ldt} = \int(T-V)dt = \int((1/2) m v^2 + GmM/r)dt$$

Applying the equation:

$$H+\partial{S}/\partial{t} = 0$$

=>

$$((1/2) m v^2 - GmM/r) +\partial({\int((1/2) m v^2 + GmM/r)dt})/\partial{t} = 0$$

For uniform circular motion $v$ is constant and $r$ is constant.

=> 
$((1/2) m v^2 - GmM/r)$ = - $\partial({(1/2) m v^2 (t-t0) + GmM/r(t-t0)})/\partial{t}$

$(1/2) m v^2 - GmM/r$ = - $(1/2) m v^2 - GmM/r$

=>

$v = 0$

what is going wrong with this equation?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: For starter, it seems OP is conflating the action functional $S[q;t_f,t_i]$ and Hamilton's principal function $S(q,\alpha,t)$. For their definitions and how they are interrelated, see e.g. my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/32277/2451).