# Hamilton-Jacobi equation and Action Functional

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, hamiltonian-formalism, variational-principle, action

Let the *action functional* $S[q]$ given by
\begin{equation}\label{eq16}
    S[q]=\int\limits^{t_2}_{t_1}L\left(q^i(t),\dot{q}^i(t)\right)dt.\tag{1}
\end{equation}
Also, we know that using Legendre Transform the hamiltonian $H(q^i,p_i)$ is related with $L(q^i,\dot{q}^i)$ by
\begin{equation}
    L(q^i,\dot{q}^i)=p_i q^i - H(q^i,p_i) \quad \text{with} \quad p_i=\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}^i}\tag{2}
\end{equation}
Thus, replacing this last equation inside the action function we have
\begin{align}\label{eq105}
    S(q,t)&=\int\limits^t_{t_0}p_i(t)\dot{q}^i(t)dt-\int\limits^t_{t_0}H(q^i(t),p_i(t))dt\tag{3}\\
    S(q,t)&=\int\limits^{q(t)}_{q(t_0)}p_i(t)dq^i-\int\limits^t_{t_0}H(q^i(t),p_i(t))dt.\tag{4}
\end{align}
Finally, we also know the diferential form of $S(q,t)$ is by definition
\begin{equation}\label{eq110}
    dS(q^i,t)=\frac{\partial S(q^i,t)}{\partial q^i}dq^i + \frac{\partial S(q^i,t)}{\partial t}dt\tag{5}
\end{equation}
which give us these following relations
\begin{equation}
    p_i=\frac{\partial S(q^i,t)}{\partial q^i} \quad \text{and} \quad -H(q^i,p_i)=\frac{\partial S(q^i,t)}{\partial q^i}.\tag{6}
\end{equation}
Replacing $p_i$ relation inside $H$ give us the **Hamilton-Jacobi equation**
\begin{equation}\label{eq116}
    \frac{\partial S(q^i,t)}{\partial t}+H\left(q^i,\frac{\partial S(q^i,t)}{\partial q^i}\right)=0.\tag{7}
\end{equation}

**Question** When working with action functional we already know that physical motions are those curves that are the an extremum of $S[q]$. But here we actually wrote $S[q]$ as a function $S(q,t)$ of $(q,t)$ and this give us Hamilton-Jacobi equation. My question is:

- Every solution of Hamilton-Jacobi equation is an extremum of $S[q]$?
- Also, there's an relation (even conceptually) between extremum of $S[q]$ and general solutions of Hamilton-Jacobi equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Eq. (1) is the off-shell action functional $S[q]$.
2. Eqs. (3)-(4) are presumably the (Dirichlet) on-shell action function $S(q_f,t_f;q_i,t_i)$. It satisfies eqs. (5)-(6), which are proven in a Lemma of my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/19944/2451).
3. Hamilton's principal function $S(q,\alpha,t)$ is the solution to [Hamilton-Jacobi equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamilton%E2%80%93Jacobi_equation) (7).

OP's main questions (v2) seems a bit like asking to compare apples and oranges. Presumably they want to ask about relationships between the 3 above objects denoted with the same letter $S$. This is explained in my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/32277/2451).