# Partial time derivative of the on-shell action

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, action, variational-calculus, functional-derivatives

I have a few questions about differentiating the on-shell action.

Here is what I currently understand (or think I do!):

1. Given that a system with Lagrangian $\mathcal{L}(\mathbf{q}, \dot{\mathbf{q}}, t)$ has the coordinate $\mathbf{q}_1$ at time $t_1$, and the coordinate $\mathbf{q}_2$ at time $t_2$, there exists a unique 'extremal path' $\gamma(t_1, \mathbf{q}_1, t_2, \mathbf{q}_2; t)$ which makes the action functional
   $$
   \mathcal{S}[\mathbf{q}(t)] = \int_{t_1}^{t_2} \mathcal{L}(\mathbf{q}, \dot{\mathbf{q}}, t)\text{d}t
   $$
   stationary. In other words, $\gamma$ satisfies the Euler-Lagrange equations, 
   $$
   \left.\left(\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial q} -\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{q}}  \right)\right|_{q(t) = \gamma(t)} = \mathbf{0},
   $$
   and has $\gamma(t_1, \mathbf{q}_1, t_2, \mathbf{q}_2; t_1) = \mathbf{q}_1$ and $\gamma(t_1, \mathbf{q}_1, t_2, \mathbf{q}_2; t_2) = \mathbf{q}_2$.
2. Moreover, the existence of this function allows the velocity, momentum etc. to be defined at the endpoints, e.g. the momentum at $(t_2, \mathbf{q}_2)$ is 
   $$
   \mathbf{p}_2 = \left.\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{\gamma}(t)}\right|_{t=t_2},
   $$
   where $\dot{\gamma} \equiv \partial \gamma(t_2, \mathbf{q}_2; t) /\partial t$.
3. Ignoring $t_1$ and $\mathbf{q}_2$ for simplicity, this allows the on-shell action (see [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/32268/)) to be defined as 
   $$
   s(t_2, \mathbf{q}_2) = \int_{t_1}^{t_2} \mathcal{L}(\gamma(t_2, \mathbf{q}_2; t), \dot{\gamma}(t_2, \mathbf{q}_2; t), t)\, \text{d} t. \tag{1}
   $$
   Importantly, $s$ is a *function* of $t_2$, $\mathbf{q}_2$, and *not* a functional. It can therefore be differentiated as any other function.
4. It is shown in *Landau* that

   > $$
   > \frac{\partial s}{\partial t_2} = -\mathcal{H}_2, \quad \frac{\partial s}{\partial \mathbf{q}_2} = \mathbf{p}_2, \tag{2}
   > $$

   but I don't follow the argument given.

I would like to derive the equations (2) by directly differentiating (1). I have read several answers which derive this in a different way ([here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/19944/), [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/144281/) and [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/383431/)), but I still have some questions. Firstly, here is my attempt at differentiating with respect to $\mathbf{q}_2$.

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial s}{\partial \mathbf{q}_2} &= \frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{q}_2} \int_{t_1}^{t_2} \mathcal{L}(\gamma(t_2, \mathbf{q}_2; t), \dot{\gamma}(t_2, \mathbf{q}_2; t), t)\, \text{d} t \\
&= \int_{t_1}^{t_2} \frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{q}_2} \mathcal{L}(\gamma(t_2, \mathbf{q}_2; t), \dot{\gamma}(t_2, \mathbf{q}_2; t), t)\, \text{d} t\\
&= \int_{t_1}^{t_2} \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \gamma}\cdot\frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial \mathbf{q}_2} +\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{\gamma}}\cdot\frac{\partial \dot{\gamma}}{\partial \mathbf{q}_2} \text{d}t.
\end{align}
Now, 
$$
\frac{\partial \dot{\gamma}}{\partial \mathbf{q}_2}  =\frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{q}_2} \frac{\text{d}\gamma}{\text{d} t}  =  \frac{\text{d}}{\text{d} t} \frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial \mathbf{q}_2},
$$
so we can integrate by parts to yield
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial s}{\partial \mathbf{q}_2} &= \left[ \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{\gamma}} \cdot \frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial \mathbf{q}_2}\right]_{t_1}^{t_2} + \int_{t_1}^{t_2} \underbrace{\left(\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \gamma} - \frac{\text{d}}{\text{d} t} \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{\gamma}}\right)}_{\mathbf{0}}\cdot\frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial \mathbf{q}_2} \text{d} t\\
&=\mathbf{p}_2\cdot\frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial \mathbf{q}_2}(t_2).
\end{align}
For (2) to be true, we ought to have $\frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial \mathbf{q}_2}(t_2) = \mathbf{I}$. Is it valid interchange the order of evaluation and differentiation to write
$$
\left.\frac{\partial \gamma(t_2, \mathbf{q}_2; t)}{\partial \mathbf{q}_2}\right|_{t=t_2} = \frac{\partial \gamma(t_2, \mathbf{q}_2; t_2)}{\partial \mathbf{q}_2} = \frac{\partial \mathbf{q}_2}{\partial \mathbf{q}_2} =\mathbf{I}?\tag{3}
$$
If so, why? If not, then how else is it possible to arrive at equation (2) from here?

Secondly, here is my attempt at differentiating with respect to $t_2$.
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial s}{\partial t_2} &= \frac{\partial}{\partial t_2} \int_{t_1}^{t_2} \mathcal{L}(\gamma(t_2, \mathbf{q}_2; t), \dot{\gamma}(t_2, \mathbf{q}_2; t), t)\, \text{d} t \\
&=  \mathcal{L}_2 + \int_{t_1}^{t_2} \frac{\partial}{\partial t_2} \mathcal{L}(\gamma(t_2, \mathbf{q}_2; t), \dot{\gamma}(t_2, \mathbf{q}_2; t), t)\, \text{d} t\\
&=\mathcal{L}_2 +  \int_{t_1}^{t_2} \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \gamma}\cdot\frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial t_2} +\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{\gamma}}\cdot\frac{\partial \dot{\gamma}}{\partial t_2} \text{d}t\\
&= \mathcal{L}_2 +\left[ \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{\gamma}} \cdot \frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial t_2}\right]_{t_1}^{t_2} + \int_{t_1}^{t_2} \underbrace{\left(\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \gamma} - \frac{\text{d}}{\text{d} t} \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{\gamma}}\right)}_{\mathbf{0}}\cdot\frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial t_2} \text{d} t\\
&=\mathcal{L}_2 + \mathbf{p}_2\cdot\frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial t_2}(t_2)
\end{align}
To get from the first to the second line I used Leibniz' rule for differentiating integrals. For equation (2) to be true, we ought to have 
$$
\frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial t_2}(t_2) = -\dot{\mathbf{q}}_2.\tag{4}
$$
Is this correct? If so, how can it be shown?

I would be very grateful for any help anyone is able to give!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:

- Eq. (3) follows from the boundary condition 
  $$\gamma(t_2, \mathbf{q}_2; t\!=\!t_2)~=~\mathbf{q}_2. \tag{A}$$
- Eq. (4) follows by differentiating eq. (A) wrt. $t_2$:
  $$  \left.\frac{\partial\gamma(t_2, \mathbf{q}_2; t)}{\partial t_2}\right|_{t=t_2}
  + \left. \frac{\partial\gamma(t_2, \mathbf{q}_2; t)}{\partial t}\right|_{t=t_2}~=~0.\tag{B}$$