# Minus sign in the definition of relativistic momentum

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, momentum, metric-tensor, relativity, conventions

Let's take metric tensor $η_{μν}=(+,-,-,-)$ and Lagrangian  $L=-m\sqrt{\dot{x}_{\mu }\dot{x}^{\mu }}$ .By the definition of momentum

$$p_{\alpha }=\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x}^{\alpha }}=-\frac{m\dot{x}%
_{\alpha }}{\sqrt{\dot{x}_{\mu }\dot{x}^{\mu }}}$$
or $p^{\alpha}=-\frac{m\dot{x}^{\alpha }}{\sqrt{\dot{x}_{\mu }\dot{x}^{\mu }}}$ then we fix $x^{0}=t$ and finaly we get

$$p^{0}=E=-\frac{m}{\sqrt{1-v^{2}}}$$

$$\vec{p}=-\frac{m\vec{v}}{\sqrt{1-v^{2}}}$$

So there is extra minus sign in the definition energy-momentum. 
Should we define the momentum with minus sign?

$$p_{\alpha }=-\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x}^{\alpha }}$$

Comment: I  choose $c=1$ .

Comment: Dot is derivative by $t$ . I fix gauge $x^{0}=t$

Comment: Why the Lagrangian needs a minus sign?

Comment: @Mauricio the minus sign gives the correct non relativistic expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, OP is right. In the Minkowski sign convention $(\color{red}{\mp}, \color{red}{\pm}, \color{red}{\pm}, \color{red}{\pm})$, the momentum 4-covector is defined as

$$ p_{\mu}~:=~ \color{red}{\pm} \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x}^{\mu}}, $$

respectively. See also [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/350820/2451) related Phys.SE post.