# In which cases does the action obey $\frac{\partial S}{\partial t}=-E$?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, schroedinger-equation, action, semiclassical

I'm reading [https://web.physics.utah.edu/~starykh/phys7640/Lectures/FeynmansDerivation.pdf](https://web.physics.utah.edu/%7Estarykh/phys7640/Lectures/FeynmansDerivation.pdf) and the article states that there are cases where the action obeys $\frac{\partial S}{\partial t}=-E$. Is this in general true, and how can this equation be derived?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Derivation of $\partial S / \partial t = -H$ for non-classical trajectories](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/358874/)