# Application of Noether's theorem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, noethers-theorem

> Consider one parameter transformation: $y = y ( \tilde{y}, \alpha)$ such that lagrangian satisfies: $\tilde{L}(\tilde{y}, \alpha) = L(y  ( \tilde{y}, \alpha))$. We say that equation is invariant under this transformation if: $$\tilde{L}(\tilde{y}, \alpha) = L(\tilde{y}) + \frac{dF(\tilde{y},\alpha)}{dt}$$
>   Show that:
>   $$\int \frac{\delta L}{\delta y_t} \frac{\partial y}{\partial \alpha} dx - \frac{\partial F}{\partial \alpha}$$
>   is a constant of motion.

Here $\tilde{y}$ is an old field before transformation, so is lagrangian $\tilde{L}$.
Space is 2-dimensional $(x, t)$ and the exercise is listed in section concerning KdV equation.

Any hints?

Comment: Which textbook is the exercise from?

Comment: @Qmechanic I don't know. Lecturer gave me a list of homework tasks without specifying the source.

Comment: Is it possible to link to a file with the original problem formulation?

Comment: @Qmechanic here is an original in polish: http://sdrv.ms/YfdHvx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since OP's [problem](http://sdrv.ms/YfdHvx) looks like a homework assignment, we will only provide OP with a series of hints rather than a full solution.

I) The Lagrangian $L~=~\int \! dx ~{\cal L}$ is the spatial integral of the Lagrangian density ${\cal L}$. Let us call the position field $q(x,t)$ and the corresponding velocity field $v(x,t)$. The Lagrangian $L[q(\cdot,t),v(\cdot,t)]$ is a *functional* of the position and the velocity fields, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/27022/2451) Phys.SE answer. The momentum field is the [functional derivative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative)

$$ \tag{1} p(x,t)~:=~\frac{\delta L[q(\cdot,t),v(\cdot,t)]}{\delta v(x,t)}.$$

An infinitesimal variation $\delta L$ of the Lagrangian functional $L$ is given by
$$\tag{2}   \delta L~=~\int \! dx~\left( \frac{\delta L}{\delta q}\delta q+\frac{\delta L}{\delta v}\delta v \right).
$$
The exercise basically asks OP to derive a functional version of [Noether's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem), which he probably knows for ordinary point mechanics.

II) Let 
$$\tag{3} \delta q~=~\varepsilon Y$$ 
be an infinitesimal variation of the position field,
where $\varepsilon$ is an infinitesimal constant, and where $Y$ is the generator. Correspondingly, the velocity field transforms as 
$$\tag{4}\delta v~=~\varepsilon \dot{Y}.$$
(The transformation (3) is a so-called *vertical* transformation. In general, one could also allow *horizontal* contributions from variation of $x$ and $t$.)

III) Assume that the transformation (2) is a so-called *quasi-symmetry*
$$\tag{5} \delta\left(\left. L \right|_{v=\dot{q}}\right)~=~ \varepsilon\frac{d}{dt} \left(\left. F\right|_{v=\dot{q}}\right),$$ 
where $F[q(\cdot,t),v(\cdot,t)]$ is some functional. (If $F=0$ is zero, then the quasi-symmetry becomes a *symmetry* of the Lagrangian $L$.)

IV) The (temporal component of the) bare [Noether current](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem) $j^0$ for a vertical transformation (3) is simply the momentum field $p$ times the vertical generator $Y$,

$$\tag{6} j^0 ~:=~p Y. $$

The bare Noether charge $Q^0$ is the spatial integral

$$\tag{7} Q^0 ~:=~ \int \! dx~j^0. $$

The full Noether charge $Q$ is improved with (minus) the $F$-functional,

$$\tag{8} Q ~:=~Q^0-F. $$

Formula (8) corresponds to OP's last formula (v1). Noether's Theorem states that $Q$ is a conserved quantity *on-shell,* i.e. if the equation of motion

$$\tag{9} \left.\frac{d}{dt} \left(\frac{\delta L}{\delta v}\right|_{v=\dot{q}}\right)~=~\left. \frac{\delta L}{\delta q}\right|_{v=\dot{q}} $$

is satisfied. The proof in the functional setting is very similar to the usual proof given in ordinary point mechanics.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My main problem is how does the partial derivative $\partial F / \partial \alpha$ appears? I can't see this one.

Comment: @qoqosz: The first order contribution is $\alpha~\partial F / \partial \alpha$ in the notation of the exercise. This should be identified with $\varepsilon F$ in my notation.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I must think on this a little more but it's definitely clearer now.