# Dimension analysis in Derrick theorem

Tags: quantum-field-theory, field-theory, variational-principle, non-linear-systems, solitons

The following image is taken from p. 85 in the textbook *Topological Solitons* by N. Manton and P.M. Sutcliffe:

[image]
[image]

> What I don't understand from the above statement:
>
> - why $e(\mu)$ has minimum for $d=2,3$, whereas when $d=4$, $e(\mu)$ is scale independent and stationary points and vacuum solutions are possible?
> - How $e(\mu)$ is a continuous function bounded by zero?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/62858/ and http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/62924/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generalized versions of [Derrick's No-Go Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derrick%27s_theorem) compare spatially scaled, non-trivial, time-independent, finite-energy, classical, field-configurations to exclude the existence of static [solitons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soliton). (Since we are only considering time-independent field-configurations, there is no kinetic energy $T=0$. Therefore the [stationary action principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_action) $\delta S=0$ amounts to minimize the (potential) energy $T+V$. Here $S:=\int \! dt ~L$, and $L:=T-V$. See also [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/61890/2451) Phys.SE post.)

Let $d$ be the number of spatial dimensions. The (potential) energy of the $\mu$-scaled configuration is

$$ \tag{4.22} e(\mu)~=~\sum_{n\in\{0,2,4\}} \mu^{n-d} E_n\geq 0,  $$

where we assume that the scale parameter

$$ \tag{A}\mu~\in~]0,\infty[ $$

is strictly positive, and that the energies

$$\tag{B} E_n~\geq ~0, \qquad n\in\{0,2,4\}$$

are non-negative. From this it already follows that the ($\mu$-scaled potential) energy $e:]0,\infty[\to [0,\infty[$ is a *non-negative* and *continuous* function, and in particular that it is bounded from below, cf. some of OP's subquestions (v1).

1. Case $E_0,E_4>0$ and $d\leq 3$: Then 
   $$\tag{C} e(0)~:=~\lim_{\mu\to 0^{+}}e(\mu)~=~\infty~=~\lim_{\mu\to \infty}e(\mu)~=:~e(\infty),$$ 
   so that there must exist an interior$^1$ (relative) minimum, and therefore Derrick's No-Go conclusion does not apply.
2. Case $d\geq 4$: The function $e$ is *monotonically weakly decreasing.* [The 
   word *weakly* means here that it could be (locally) constant.] The only possibility to have an interior minimum (and therefore evade Derrick's No-Go conclusion) is if $E_0=0=E_2$ and if moreover either (i) $d=4$ or (ii) $E_4=0$. The former case corresponds to pure 4+1 gauge theory, which indeed has non-trivial static soliton solutions with $E_4>0$. The latter case corresponds to vacuum solutions $e\equiv 0$. The function $e$ is in both cases a constant function, i.e. independent of the scale $\mu$.
3. Case $E_0=0=E_2$: The function $e$ is [*monotonic*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function). The only possibility to have an interior minimum (and therefore evade Derrick's No-Go conclusion) is, if (i) $d=4$, or if (ii) $E_4=0$, i.e. we are back in the previous case (2).

References:

1. N. Manton and P.M. Sutcliffe, *Topological Solitons,* 2004, Section 4.2.
2. S. Coleman, *Aspects of symmetry,* 1985. Note that Sidney calls *solitons* for *lumps.*
3. R. Rajaraman, *Solitons and Instantons: An Introduction to Solitons and Instantons in Quantum Field Theory,* 1987.

--

$^1$ An *interior* minimum  point $\mu$ means that $\mu$ is different from the boundary $0$ and $\infty$.