# Violation of Derrick's theorem for finite energy, time independent solutions?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, gauge-theory, classical-field-theory, vortex, solitons

How are vortices the finite energy time independent solutions for 2+1 dimensions abelian Higgs model? Doesn't it violate Derrick's theorem that there are no finite energy time independent solutions in dimensions higher than 1+1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not a violation. The conclusion of [Derrick's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derrick%27s_theorem) is modified in the presence of gauge fields, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/75526/2451) Phys.SE post.

Answer (score 1):

No, it does not violate. Derrick's theorem is actually very restricted. It says that there is no finite energy time independent solution for
$$L=\frac{1}{2}\partial_\mu\phi\partial^\mu\phi-V(\phi),$$
in dimensions larger than $1+1$. The vortice in the Abelian-Higgs model appears for the lagrangian
$$L=-\frac 14F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}+(D_\mu\phi)^*D^\mu\phi-\frac{\lambda}{4}(|\phi|^2-v^2)^2,$$
in $2+1$ or $3+1$. This is a gauge theory and the gauge field provides "more structure" to the theory, allowing for finite time independent solutions.

The intuition is that the for the first theory, there is a term $\int rdr\partial_i\phi\partial_i\phi$ in the energy density of the possible vortex but this diverges logarithmically. The corresponding term for the second theory is $\int rdr (D_i\phi)^*D_i\phi$ and the presence of the gauge field $A$ turns it possible that $D_i\phi=\partial_i\phi+ieA_i\phi$ decays sufficiently fast.