# What does lowercase-delta mean in Noether's first theorem?

Tags: classical-mechanics, notation, differentiation, noethers-theorem, functional-derivatives

Most expressions of [Noether's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem) I have come across do not use lowercase delta, but a couple sites do.      I am confused.......    Check out page 21 of the June 23 issue of 'Science News' magazine.
$$
\frac{d}{dt} \left(\sum_a \frac{δL}{δ\dfrac{dq_a}{dt}}δq_a\right) = 0.
$$

References:

1. [Science News Vol. 193, No. 11, June 23, 2018, p. 20](https://www.sciencenews.org/article/emmy-noether-theorem-legacy-physics-math?mode=magazine&context=194583).

Comment: $\uparrow$ Which sites? Link to sites?

Comment: I just wrote the equation that appeared in the June 23, 2018 issue of 'Science News' as best I could......

Comment: This is standard notation in the calculus of variations. Check out Goldstein's Classical Mechanics for instance.

Answer (score 2):

There is really too little context to be sure what the author meant but the formula looks superficially like the Noether conservation law for vertical variations in point mechanics (rather than field theory). The $\delta$ usually means functional derivatives, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/153791/2451) Phys.SE post. However functional derivatives wrt. velocity does not make sense without further explanation, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/263261/2451) & [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/80430/2451) Phys.SE posts.

Let us from now on restrict to the case where the Lagrangian $L(q,\dot{q},t)$ only depends on up to first time derivatives. Then the vertical Noether current is a product of a vertical generator and the momemtum $p = \partial L / \partial \dot{q}$. Note in particular that the momentum is constructed via partial differentiation *not* functional differentiation.