# Variations wrt. Time Derivatives

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, differentiation, variational-calculus, functional-derivatives

I've been working on my dynamics homework when I've run into confusion with derivatives and could use some help regarding that. The question is as follows:

When varying a functional with respect to a variable, do we consider different derivatives of functions to be independent? For instance, what is the functional derivative of $\ddot{x}$ with respect to $\dot{x}$?

For instance, I have an equation $L = x + \dot{x}+\ddot{x}$.
What is the partial derivative of this with respect to $\dot{x}$?

Comment: $\ddot x$ isn’t a [functional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_(mathematics)) so you can’t take its functional derivative with respect to anything.

Comment: The action is a functional $S = \int{\rm d}t L$.

Comment: @David can you clarify what you mean? I'm unsure how to apply that to the derivatives of x-dot

Comment: A functional is an object that depends on functions, but not their dependent variables. Example: Because the action $S$ is the integral of the Lagrangian over time, it only depends on the functions $x,\dot x$ etc, but not $t$.

Comment: @David oh were you responding to the person above you with your comment/ I wasn't sure if that was an answer because It didn't clarify it for me. I guess I'm asking for a general case for how this derivative with respect to x-dot would work as x-dot varies with time

Comment: Unanswerable as asked.  Partial derivatives are slot derivatives.  You have declared $L = x + \dot{x} + \ddot{x}$, failing to declare slots.  Until you write something like "$L(x, \dot{x}, \ddot{x}) = \dots$", you can't take the partial derivate of $L$ with respect to anything.  Afterwards, $\partial L / \partial \dot{x}$ is the derivative of $L$ with respect to variation of its second slot (holding the other slots, including $\ddot{x}$, constant).

Answer (score 13):

This is a fairly common misconception.
The action functional $S$ eats a **function** $q$ and spits out the following number:

$$S[q] := \int_{t_1}^{t_2} L\big(q(t),\dot q(t), t\big)\ dt$$

where the Lagrangian $L: \mathbb R^3 \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is just a function of three variables.  One might have, for example,

$$L(a,b,c) = \frac{1}{2} mb^2 - \frac{1}{2} m\omega^2 a^2$$

where $m$ and $\omega$ are constants.  In that case, the action would be

$$S[q] := \int_{t_1}^{t_2} L\big(q(t),\dot q(t),t\big) = \int_{t_1}^{t_2} \left(\frac{1}{2}m \dot q^2(t) - \frac{1}{2}m\omega^2 q^2(t) \right) dt$$

---

Given some $(a,b,c)$, we can linearize the Lagrangian to find its value at a nearby point $(a+\delta a,b+\delta b,c+\delta c)$:

$$L(a+\delta a,b+\delta b,c+\delta c) = L(a,b,c) + \left[ \big(\partial_1L\big)\cdot \delta a+ \big(\partial_2L\big)\cdot \delta b +\big(\partial_3L\big)\cdot \delta c\right]$$

where $\partial_nL$ is the derivative of $L$ with respect to its $n^{th}$ slot.  Therefore, if we add a small $\eta$ to $q$, we get

$$S[q+\eta]=\int_{t_1}^{t_2} L\big(q(t)+\eta(t),\dot q(t) + \dot \eta(t),t\big) \ dt $$
$$\simeq \int_{t_1}^{t_2} L\big(q(t),\dot q(t),t\big)\ dt + \int_{t_1}^{t_2} \big[(\partial_1 L) \eta(t) + (\partial_2 L) \dot \eta(t) \big] dt$$

Integration by parts then gives

$$S[q+\eta]-S[q]\simeq \int_{t_1}^{t_2} \big[(\partial_1 L) - \frac{d}{dt}(\partial_2 L)\big]\eta \ dt$$

where we've used the fact that $\eta(t_1)=\eta(t_2)=0$.  If we demand that this vanish for arbitrary (differentiable) $\eta$, we must have that

$$\frac{d}{dt}\left[\bigg(\partial_2 L\bigg)\big(q(t),\dot q(t),t\big)\right] = \bigg(\partial_1 L\bigg)\big(q(t),\dot q(t),t\big)$$

---

Notation being what it is, it is standard to say something like
$$L(x,v,t) = \frac{1}{2}m v^2 + \frac{1}{2}m\omega^2x^2$$
$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial x} = m\omega^2 x$$
$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial v} = mv$$

But this is a bit misleading.  What we've written as $\frac{\partial L}{\partial x}$ is really the derivative of $L$ with respect to its first slot, *evaluated at the point* $(x,v,t)$.  The same is true when we write $L = L(q,\dot q,t)$; the fact that $q$ and $\dot q$ are related to each other by differentiation is irrelvant, because $q(t)$ and $\dot q(t)$ are the *values* (not functions!) we plug in to the first and second slots *after* we take the partial derivative of $L$.

---

> I have an equation $L=x+\dot x+\ddot x$. What is the partial derivative of this with respect to $\dot x$?

$L$ is a function, not a functional; it doesn't know how to take derivatives.  It is a map which eats numerical values and spits out a numerical value.  The only way to have a Lagrangian like that is to define $L(a,b,c)=a+b+c$, and then plug $x$ into the first slot, $\dot x$ into the second slot, and $\ddot x$ into the third slot$^\dagger$.  If you do this, then $\big(\partial_2 L\big)(x,\dot x,\ddot x)$, which we we would usually write as $\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot x}$ in an abuse of notation, would be equal to $1$.

---

$^\dagger$ Note that an action functional which involves second derivatives is mathematically problematic under most circumstances.

Comment: Thank you for having taken the time to clarify the usual abuses of notations! As a result you managed to write the best explanation of the Lagrangian I have ever read.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the cheat sheet:

- On one hand, in a [**partial** differentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_derivative) the variable $x,\dot{x},\ddot{x},\ldots$ are **independent.** E.g. the partial derivatives $\frac{\partial \dot{x}}{\partial x}=0$ and $\frac{\partial x}{\partial \dot{x}}=0$ are zero.
- On the other hand, in a [**functional** differentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative) the variable $x,\dot{x},\ddot{x},\ldots$ are **dependent.** E.g. the functional derivative $\frac{\delta \dot{x}(t)}{\delta x(t^{\prime})}=\delta^{\prime}(t\!-\!t^{\prime})$ and $\frac{\delta \ddot{x}(t)}{\delta x(t^{\prime})}=\delta^{\prime\prime}(t\!-\!t^{\prime})$ are derivatives of the [Dirac delta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function), while $\frac{\delta x(t)}{\delta \dot{x}(t^{\prime})}$ or $\frac{\delta \ddot{x}(t)}{\delta \dot{x}(t^{\prime})}$ are ill-defined/meaningless.

This is explained further in e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/885/2451) and [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/263261/2451) related Phys.SE posts.

Answer (score 2):

I am going to guess that you are working in the context of a Lagrangian, trying to derive the equation of motion.  The Lagrangian for one-dimensional motion along a single direction $x$ is a function $L(\dot{x},x)$.  (It can also be a function of $t$, but that’s not directly relevant for this discussion.)  To derive the Euler-Lagrange equations, you need to take partial derivatives of $L$ with respect to both $x$ and $\dot{x}$, and this is done by considering $x$ and $\dot{x}$ to be completely independent variables.

Instead of $L(\dot{x},x)$, you can think of the Lagrangian as a function of two completely separate variables $L(y,x)$.  Then the partial derivate with respect to $\dot{x}$ is essentially *defined* to be
$$\frac{\partial L(\dot{x},x)}{\partial\dot{x}}\equiv\left.\frac{\partial L(y,x)}{\partial y}\right|_{y=\dot{x}},$$
taking the derivative of $L$ with respect to its first argument and evaluating it at that argument equal to $\dot{x}$.

When dealing with more complicated theories (involving not point particles but fields), defined in terms of an action $S=\int dt\,L$, the relationship between $\partial/\partial x$ and $\partial/\partial\dot{x}$ can be made more apparent, but at the at the level you are talking about, what I have described is probably the best way to think about things.  This means, by the way, that the partial derivative $\partial L/\partial\dot{x}$ of the $L=x+\dot{x}+\ddot{x}$ in the question is just 1—as are $\partial L/\partial x$ and $\partial L/\partial\ddot{x}$

Comment: oh this makes sense! You are right - I am analyzing a double pendulum and part of the differential equation uses a partial with respect to x-dot. 

so as an addition, in my case x-dot varies with time - so would the partial with respect to x-dot not be x-dot-dot as the differentiation is not related to time, but in fact the x-dot term?