# Definition of the Lagrangian in (classical) field theory

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, definition, variational-calculus, functional-derivatives

I am currently reading through Weinberg's *Lectures on Quantum Mechanics*. Chapter 11 deals with field theory:

> Correspondingly, the Lagrangian $L(t)$ is a functional of $\psi_n(\vec{x}, t)$ and $\dot{\psi}_n(\vec{x}, t)$, depending on the form of all of the functions $\psi_n(x, t)$ and $\dot{\psi}_n(x, t)$ for all $\vec{x}$, but at a fixed time $t$.

I understand the statement above in the following way: the Lagrangian, as a functional, takes the fields $\psi_n$ and $\dot{\psi}_n$ and a specific value of $t$ as input and produces some output that is not dependent of $\vec{x}$.

Is this "interpretation" correct and if not, what else does is mean?
At least it would make sense to me, especially when the Lagrangian is defined as

> $L(t) = \int \, d^3x \cal{L}\big(\psi(\vec{x},t), \vec{\nabla}\psi(\vec{x},t),\dot{\psi}(\vec{x},t)\big)$.

Comment: That is correct. It takes the functions $\psi_n(\vec{x})$ and ${\dot \psi}_n(\vec{x})$ which are the values of $\psi_n$ and ${\dot \psi}_n$ at a particular value of $t$ as inputs. The output is a number independent of $\vec{x}$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Perhaps it would be more pedagogical to use the notation $q$ and $v$ as the notation for the fields $\psi$ and $\dot{\psi}$, respectively, because they are  *independent* fields: $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\to\mathbb{R}$ in the Lagrangian functional $L[q(\cdot,t),v(\cdot,t);t]$.

   On the other hand, in the action $S[q]$ the 2 fields are actually *dependent.* For the explanation in the simpler situation of point mechanics, see e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/885/2451) Phys.SE post.
2. OP interpretation is correct. The Lagrangian is a map
   $$ F(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}) \times F(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}) \times \mathbb{R}~~\stackrel{L}{\longrightarrow}~~\mathbb{R}, $$
   where $F(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R})$ denotes an appropriate class of functions: $\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$.
   In particular, spatial derivatives $\vec{\nabla}\psi(\vec{x},t)$ are also allowed in a first-order Lagrangian density ${\cal L}$.
3. For a higher-order Lagrangian density ${\cal L}$, see e.g. my related Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/27022/2451).