# The principle of stationary action?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, variational-principle, action

In proving that the action $$S\equiv \int^{t_2}_{t_1}L(x, x',t)dt$$ has a has a stationary point $x_0$ that satisfies the following:
$$\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{\partial L}{\partial x'_0})=\frac{\partial L}{\partial x_0}$$
My textbook finds the action of $$x_a(t)\equiv x_0(t)+a\beta (t)$$ differentiated with respect a to the first order to reach the expression:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial a} S[x_a(t)]=\int^{t_2}_{t_1}(\frac{\partial L}{\partial x_a} - \frac{d}{dt}(\frac{\partial L}{\partial x'_a}))\beta dt$$
It then says that the only way this can be 0 for all $\beta$ is if the expression in the parentheses evaluated at $a=0$ is identically equal to zero. I don't understand why we can evaluate it at 0, please could someone explain? (I would understand if the thing in the parentheses had to be 0 for all $a$ but why does been it been 0 for $a=0$ imply it is 0 for all $a$?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comment to the question (v1): Consider the composed function

$$s(a)~:=~ S[x_a] , $$

where

$$x_a(t) ~=~ x_0(t) + a \beta(t),$$

for fixed $\beta$.

It should be stressed that the function $a\mapsto s(a)$ is *not* necessarily independent of $a$, or equivalently, the derivative $s^{\prime}(a)$ is *not* necessarily zero for all $a$, even if $x_0(t)$ is a [stationary path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_action).

However, if $x_0(t)$ is a stationary path, then $s^{\prime}(0)=0$ by definition.

The full derivation of [Euler-Lagrange equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation) from the [stationary action principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_action) is done in many textbooks and websites, e.g. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation). For more information, see also e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/885/2451) Phys.SE post.