# If momentum is a covector, how does $p=mv$?

Tags: classical-mechanics, differential-geometry, momentum, coordinate-systems, covariance

There are several explanations on this site [[1]](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/351903/simple-explanation-of-why-momentum-is-a-covector) [[2]](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/176555/momentum-is-a-cotangent-vector) [[3]](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/172789/what-is-the-function-type-of-the-generalized-momentum) about why momentum is a covector while velocity is a vector. This distinction is important for the geometric description of classical mechanics.

However, none of these explanations reconciles this with the seeming contradiction that $p=mv$, which on its face suggests that momentum and velocity are the same type of object. **How can we resolve this apparent contradiction?**

---

I would expect that $p=mv$ exploits an isomorphism between the tangent and cotangent spaces, allowing us to represent $p$ as a vector even though it is "naturally" a covector. But if that's the case, how is this isomorphism defined, and where does it enter into the formalism of classical mechanics?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Yes, OP points to the fact that classical mechanics typically relies on the existence of a fiducial/distinguished/background [metric structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_tensor) on the [configuration manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Configuration_space_(physics)) so that we can apply the [musical isomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musical_isomorphism) to raise and lower indices, e.g. between the contravariant velocity vector and the covariant momentum covector.
2. *Example:* If $L=\frac{1}{2}m_{ij}v^iv^j-V$, then $p_i=\frac{\partial L}{\partial v^i}= m_{ij}v^j$. Often the mass metric structure is of the form $m_{ij}=m~g_{ij}$.
3. Concerning the related notion of [phase space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_space), see e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/136182/2451) Phys.SE post.

Comment: I am curious, though: how "formally" is the musical isomorphism defined in this case? It seems the action (given by the Lagrangian) is what provides the metric, right - esp. noting how Wikipedia suggests that "there are similar isomorphisms on symplectic manifolds", which is what the classical phase space is. However usually we think of position and momentum in CM as just a point and vector in ordinary space, so shouldn't the metric just be the usual Euclidean one? So then why/how does the Lagrangian enter in to "transpose" the vector? Also why is mass seemingly a tensor here and not a scalar?

Comment: I updated the answer.

Comment: So the metric here is the _spatial_ (i.e. Euclidean 2- or 3-dimensional, for classical mechanics) metric, right?

Comment: $\uparrow$ In many cases.