# Why does every classical dynamical variable depend on position and momentum rather than position and velocity according to Shankar?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics, momentum, velocity, hamiltonian-formalism

The statement (from Shankar's Quantum Mechanics):

> Every dynamical variable $\omega(x,p)$ is a function of $p$ and $x$

This means (I think) that a classical system can be totally determined if one knows the position and momentum of an object described by the system.

My question is: Do we have the variable depend on momentum rather than just velocity in order to make sure conserved quantities (like energy or momentum itself) which depend on mass are fully described?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/307794/2

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can equally well say that position and velocity fully describe a classical (point particle) system, the difference between using velocity or momentum is precisely the difference between the equivalent formulations of [Lagrangian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_mechanics) and [Hamiltonian mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_mechanics).

Shankar uses the momentum, i.e. the Hamiltonian formulation, because the Hamiltonian formulation is the starting point for canonical quantization, see also e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/19770/50583) or [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/46015/50583) question.