# Time translation invariance of Hamiltonian

Tags: symmetry, time, hamiltonian

I am learning about the time translation invariance of the Hamiltonian. I read that

> the time translation invariance is already manifest in the fact that our
>   Hamiltonian is chosen an instantaneous function of time—we have assumed that the dynamics only
>   depends on position and velocity at the current time, rather than the full history of the particle’s trajectory.

I do not quite understand this. The Hamiltonian for a one-dimensional point particle can be written as $$H(x,t)=\frac{[p(x,t)]^2}{2m}+V(x,t)$$ where $p(x,t)$ and $V(x,t)$ are the momentum and potential repectively. If the time translation is $t \rightarrow t+ t_0$, the Hamiltonian will become 
$$H(x,t+t_0)=\frac{[p(x,t+t_0)]^2}{2m}+V(x,t+t_0).$$
Why can one say that $H(x,t)=H(x,t+t_0)$?

Comment: The underlying confusion here seems to be about what the Hamiltonian is actually a function of. See [ŧhis answer of mine](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/307805/50583), which among other things explains why the Hamiltonian is *not* a function of $x$ and $t$.

Comment: There's nothing too deep here. If a function (of time) is invariant under time  translation then it is constant. In other words the Hamiltonian does not depends explicitly on time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the setting. You have a system that is described by some generalized coordinates $q_i$ and some generalized momenta $p_i$ (in the Lagrangian formalism, you'd use $\dot{q_i}$ instead). Hamilton's equations tell you how these $q_i$ and $p_i$ change with time.

$$\dot{q_i} = \frac{\partial H}{\partial p_i}, \dot{p_i} = -\frac{\partial H}{\partial q_i}$$

The Hamiltonian, $H = H(q_i, p_i, t)$, is a function of the $q_i$, the $p_i$ and possibly time $t$. The question about time invariance of the Hamiltonian is simply asking if there is any explicit dependence of $H$ on $t$. Consider

$$H = H(p,q) = \frac{p^2}{2m} + V(q)$$

This has no explicit dependence on time. You could easily imagine a situation where you vary the potential with time so that $V(q)$ becomes $V(q, t)$. Now, the time dependence is explicit and the Hamiltonian is not time translational invariant.

Answer (score 2):

If a function (of time) is invariant under time translation then it is constant. In other words the Hamiltonian does not depends explicitly on time.

The (admittedly a bit sibylline) paragraph that you cite wants to stress the fact that, from the get go, the Hamiltonian is assumed to be *time local* i.e., to be a function of time only at time $t$. You can have (master) equations where the generator depends on the whole history of times from the beginning to the present time. For example something of this form

$$
\frac{d\rho(t)}{dt} = \int_0^t dt' K(t,t') \rho(t') \, , 
$$

[$\rho$ could be the vector $(q,p)$]. However, we assume that the Hamiltonian is simply of the form $H(q,p,t)$. In this case time translation invariance simply means that $H$ does not depends explicitly on $t$, i.e., effectively $H=H(q,p)$.

Answer (score 1):

The potential V(x,t), if its time dependent it will make the Hamiltonian as a whole time dependent. But dependence inside of momentum p doesnt count. For example in an oscillator, $H=p^2+x^2$, and p and x are time dependent but because the potential, $V=x^2$ is not explicitly time dependent, therefore the total energy is conserved. There is a theorem which says:

$ {dH \over dt} = {\partial H \over \partial t} $

meaning that the total change in energy is all times equal to the change in energy due to the explicit time dependence in the potential.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to explicitly calculate $ dH = H(x,t) - H(x,t+t_0) = 0$

It would be easier to show the invariance of $H$ under spatial translations $x_0$, expressing explicitly $H$ as $1/2mv^2 + U(x)$

Please read https://www.physicswithelliot.com/noether-mini-notes

He clearly shows how to calculate $dL$. By following the example, you can probably do it yourself for $H$.