# Vectors and One-forms in Cylindrical Coordinates and the Angular Momentum

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, angular-momentum, coordinate-systems, angular-velocity

The angular component of the velocity of a particle in cylindrical coordinates has different units if we consider the vector component $v^{\phi}$ or the one-form component $v_{\phi}$:

$$ v^{\phi} = \frac{x v^y - y v^x}{r^2} ,$$
$$ v_{\phi} = x v^y - y v^x .$$
This came from the fact that we use the Jacobian matrix $J(\rm cart \rightarrow cyl) = \frac{\partial(r,\phi,z)}{\partial(x,y,z)}$ for changing the components of the vectors, while we use its inverse for changing the components of the one-forms.

while $v^{\phi}$ has the dimension of an angular velocity, $v_{\phi}$ has the dimension of a specific angular momentum.

**Question:** Can we argue something general from this example? Do we have a physical duality between vectors and one-forms, in the sense that one-forms are some conjugate variable of the vectors?

Comment: What do you mean by "physical duality"? There is of course the *general* duality between vectors and one-forms ([musical isomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musical_isomorphism), [raising and lowering indices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raising_and_lowering_indices)) on (pseudo-)Riemannian manifolds, and it seems you have used exactly that here, using the ordinary Euclidean metric on $\mathbb{R}^3$. That velocities live in the tangent bundles and momenta in the cotangent bundle is also a general notion, see e.g. https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/307794/50583.

Comment: I used the therm "physical duality" to distinguish from the musical isomorphism. The vector and one-form are two different physical quantity, in this particular case as an example, why the one-form of a velocity is an angular momentum? I could expect this can happen for many physical quantities encoded in vectors and one form.