# Partial derivative of $v$ w.r.t. $x$ in Lagrangian dynamics

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, differentiation, calculus

In Lagrangian dynamics, when using the Lagrangian thus:

$$
\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{\partial \mathcal{L} }{\partial \dot{q_j}})-
\frac{\partial \mathcal{L} }{\partial q_j} = 0
$$

often we get terms such as the one below which result in zero:

example 1:
$$
\frac{\partial \dot{q}}{\partial q} = 0
$$
example 2:
$$
\frac{\partial q}{\partial \dot{q}} = 0
$$

I wasn't sure why but this is the closest I have come to reasoning it out:

$$
\frac{\partial \dot{q}}{\partial q} = 
\frac{\partial \dot{q}}{\partial t}\frac{\partial t}{\partial q} 
= 0
$$

because

$$
\frac{\partial t}{\partial q} = 0
$$

and similar for example 2. Is this correct?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Independent Variables of a Lagrangian](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/202123/) and links therein.

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/885/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Cool, should I just delete?