# Why is the potential independent of the generalized velocity?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, velocity, potential-energy, variational-principle

In Goldstein, *Classical Mechanics*, Chap. 1.4 we derive Lagrange's equations from D'Alembert's Principle. My question is regarding the last part of the derivation, specifically the part where he introduces the Lagrangian $L$ defined as $T - V$:
$$  
\frac{d}{dt} \left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial \dot{q}_j} \right) - \frac{\partial T}{\partial q_j} - Q_j = 0 ,\tag{1.53} $$
$$ Q_j = - \frac{\partial V}{\partial q_j}. \tag{1.54}$$
Which when substituting yields:
$$
\frac{d}{dt} \left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial \dot{q}_j} \right) - \frac{\partial (T-V)}{\partial q_j} = 0\tag{1.55}.
$$

The next step is what confuses me. He states that the potential $V$ does not depend on the generalized velocities so he makes the following substitution which "has no effect on differentiation with respect to $ \dot{q}_j $":
$$
\frac{d}{dt} \left(\frac{\partial (T - V)}{\partial \dot{q}_j} \right) - \frac{\partial (T-V)}{\partial q_j} = 0. 
$$
Which leads to the familiar:
$$
\frac{d}{dt} \left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}_j} \right) - \frac{\partial L}{\partial q_j} = 0.\tag{1.57}
$$

It makes sense intuitively. After all, you can vary a particles position without effecting its instantaneous velocity at the end of its path, therefore causing a change in potential without a corresponding change in velocity.

My confusion arises when you know the equations of motion as a priori: $V$ is dependent on position, position is dependent on time (from equations of motions), and velocity is dependent on time. Doesn't this means there exists *some* relationship between the potential function and velocity?

Answer (score 4):

Comments to the question (v2):

1. First of all, it should be mentioned that Goldstein rushes to define generalized velocity-dependent potentials on the very next page
   $$ Q_j~=~ - \frac{\partial U}{\partial q^j} + \frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial v^j}\right). \tag{1.58} $$
2. It seems that the heart of OP's question is equivalent to the oft-asked question *How can position $q$ and velocity $v$ be independent variables in the Lagrangian $L(q,v,t)$?* This has been answered in e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/885/2451) Phys.SE post.

Comment: Regarding 2: For the simple example of projectile motion, you write the y-coordinate as a function of the velocity as such:$ y = y_0 + \frac{\frac{1}{2}v^{2}_0 + 2v_0v + \frac{1}{2}v^{2}}{g} $ Substituting this into the potential **V** (in this case, mgy) we see that **V** is dependent on the velocity, which seemingly contradicts ∂U/∂v = 0.

Comment: Here is one attempt to give an explanation: A solution to eoms depends on the choice of initial conditions $(q_0,v_0)$. The Lagrangian $L(q(t),v(t),t)$ (and hence the potential) is a state function, which is only allowed to depend on the state $(q(t),v(t))$ of the system in one instant $t$ at a time. If $L$ depends on more than one instant at a time, it would become non-local. In particular, it is not allowed to depend on initial conditions (which refer to another time). A more complete explanation is given in the linked post.

Comment: What is the reasoning behind why the Lagrangian must be local?

Comment: In the context of Goldstein, this is an implicit assumption.