# What is the partial derivative of a four-covector with respect to its derivative?

Tags: field-theory, differentiation

If I have a partial derivative for $A_\mu$ of the form $$\frac{\partial A_\mu}{\partial(\partial_\mu A_\upsilon)}$$ where $\partial_\mu A_\upsilon = \frac{\partial A_\upsilon}{\partial x^\mu}$ is the derivative of $A_\upsilon$ with respect to the spacetime coordinates, how do I go about evaluating this expression? In Sean Carroll's Intro to GR, he gets terms like these in equations that he seems to just discard, so I suspect the answer is $0$, but I don't know the specifics of how that results from the derivative above.

Comment: Which eq? Which page?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/885/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/526011/2451 and links therein.

Comment: @Qmechanic It would take a while to put in the equation. Should I edit the question?

Comment: Also, the first duplicate you provided answered my question. The equation was indeed the Lagrangian for electromagnetism in flat spacetime, and I did not know that the arguments of the Lagrangian were considered independent of each other.