# Confusion about Noether's theorem

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, conservation-laws, symmetry, field-theory, noethers-theorem

In my field theory class we recently derived Noether's theorem: We consider a infinitessimal transformation $\phi \to \phi + \epsilon \,\delta\phi$ of our field which preserves action i. e. $\delta S = 0$.
This last condition is supposedly equivalent to $\delta \mathcal{L}$ being a divergence, i. e. $\delta \mathcal{L} = \epsilon\,\partial_\mu I^\mu$. Then you can expand
\begin{align}
\delta \mathcal{L} &= \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \phi} \epsilon \, \delta \phi + \frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial (\partial_\mu \phi)} \epsilon \partial_\mu(\delta\phi)
\\
&= \left( - \partial_\mu \frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial (\partial_\mu \phi)} + \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \phi}\right) \epsilon \, \delta \phi
+ \partial_\mu \left( \frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial (\partial_\mu \phi)} \delta\phi\right) \epsilon
\end{align}

The first term vanishes by the eqns. of motion and so we get 
$$
\partial_\mu \left( \frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial (\partial_\mu \phi)} \delta\phi  - I^\mu\right) = 0
$$
i.e. $\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial (\partial_\mu \phi)} \delta\phi  - I^\mu$ is a conserved current.

Two things confuse me here:

We didn't use that the transformation is supposed to be a symmetry of the system (that is $\delta S = 0$). In a point-particle setting (that is a  field that only depends on time) we can have $L = T - V$ with $\partial V / \partial q \neq 0$, but we can look at a translation $q \to q + \epsilon$ which gives us
$$
L \to L + \epsilon \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \left( - t \frac{\partial V}{\partial q} \right)
$$
so $L$ is only changed up to a "divergence" and the resulting conserved quantity is $p + t \frac{\partial V}{\partial q}$, which is indeed conserved, even though our system was not space-homogeneous.

The other source of confusion (which I guess is related to the first) is this argument that $\delta S = 0$ is equivalent to $\delta \mathcal{L} = \epsilon \partial_\mu I^\mu$. In $\mathbb{R}^n$, every scalar function can be written as a divergence, so this doesn't seem to add up. Is $I^\mu$ maybe supposed to be a function of the fields only?

Answer (score 2):

There are at least 2 issues with OP's discussion (v2):

1. One should properly distinguish between *total* and *explicit* spacetime derivatives, cf. e.g. my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/255448/2451).

   In particular, an infinitesimal [quasisymmetry](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/11317/2451) of the Lagrangian (density), means by definition that the infinitesimal variation is a *total* (space)time divergence.
2. [Note that *not* all terms in a Lagrangian (density) [or variations thereof] are total (space)time divergences](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/22249/2451).

Answer (score 0):

My bad, I see now what happened, and as @Qmechanic noted above, Lagrangians are invariant under the addition of total derivatives.