# Euler-Lagrange equation of test particle in relativity

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, relativity, variational-calculus

I have trouble understanding the following. 
If $$ \mathcal{L}(x,\dot{x})=\sqrt{\eta_{\mu \nu}\frac{dx^{\mu}}{d\tau}\frac{dx^{\nu}}{d\tau}}$$
why is then $$\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial x^{\sigma}}=0~?$$

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/885/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Well, the Lagrangian does not explicitly depend on the position, therefore their corresponding derivatives vanish. And no, the velocity does **not** depend on the position either (outside the solution of the equation of motion).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is kind of simple and does not directly refer to Relativity. Because $\mathcal{L}(x,\dot{x})=\sqrt{\eta_{\mu \nu}\frac{dx^{\mu}}{d\tau}\frac{dx^{\nu}}{d\tau}}$ does not explicitly depend on  $x$ but only on $\frac{dx^{\nu}}{d\tau}$, thus
$$\mathcal{L}(x,\dot{x})=\mathcal{L}(\frac{dx^{\nu}}{d\tau}).$$
 $$\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial x^{\sigma}}=\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}(\frac{dx^{\nu}}{d\tau})}{\partial x^{\sigma}}=0$$
You can try to derive equations of motion from here.