# Variation in field theory with respect to one quantity

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, variational-calculus

In my QFT course we are supposed to vary the action of a for a scalar ﬁeld coupled to an electromagnetic ﬁeld with the following Lagrangian density:

$$\mathcal{L} = [D_\mu\phi(x)]^*D^\mu\phi(x)-m^2\phi(x)^*\phi(x) -\frac{1}{4}F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}$$

where ($D_\mu\phi(x) = (\partial_\mu+ieA_\mu(x))\phi(x)$ and $x$ is a 4-vector) with respect to $A_\mu$. But what is meant by only varying the action w.r.t to one quantity? For Example when we derived the Euler-Lagrange-Equations for a free scalar field we varied w.r.t $\phi$ and $\partial_\mu\phi$.

Comment: This is a more sophisticated variant of [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/885/calculus-of-variations-how-does-it-make-sense-to-vary-the-position-and-the-ve/) question.

Comment: And fittingly, the answers there are more sophisticated variants of my answer. OP, i really recommend the linl in knzhou's comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Varying with respect to $A_\mu$ automatically induces a variation in $\partial_\mu A_\nu$ given by

$$ \delta(\partial_\mu A_\nu) = \partial_\mu \delta A_\nu.$$

Thus, unless the text of your excercise says explicitly that you are supposed to hold $\partial_\mu A_\nu$ fixed (which i find highly unlikely, but will revise my answer in that case), I believe that you are supposed to vary both $A_\mu$ and $\partial_\mu A_\nu$.