# About Lagrange equation

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, differentiation, variational-calculus

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \left ( \frac {\partial  L}{\partial \dot{q}_j} \right ) =  \frac {\partial L}{\partial q_j}.$$

I don't understand partial derivative by "function" (e.g. $q_j$).
$q$ can be displacement. Then $\dot{q}$ is velocity. Both can be represented in terms of $t$. So by eliminating $t$, $q$ can be represented in terms of $\dot{q}$  vice versa. Hence, all $q$ terms in $L$ can be replaced with $\dot{q}$ terms making  RHS of the above equation $0$. What's wrong with this?

Comment: This post (v2) seems to be essentially the question of whether positions and velocities are independent variables or not, cf. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/885/2451) Phys.SE post.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculus of variations -- how does it make sense to vary the position and the velocity independently?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/885/)