# Partial derivative of position in respect to velocity

Tags: lagrangian-formalism

Out of interest What is the derivative of $\frac{\partial x(t)}{ \partial v(t)}$

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/885/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculus of variations -- how does it make sense to vary the position and the velocity independently?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/885/)

Answer (score 1):

Let me note that, since both $x$ and $v$ are functions of a single variable, we are dealing here not with partial derivatives but with ordinary derivatives which are equivalent to the corresponding differentials (partial derivatives are not). This may seem like a simple change of notation
$$
\frac{\partial x(t)}{\partial v(t)} \longrightarrow \frac{d x(t)}{d v(t)},
$$
but mathematically these are two different things. Importantly, ordinary derivative is actually a true ratio of two differentials, $dx = \dot{x}(t)dt, dv = \dot{v}dt$, while a partial derivative is just a symbol.

Now we can consider $x$ as a function of $v$: $x = f(v)$, which is given to us in a parametric form, with $t$ being the parameter. The ordinary derivative of this function is then just the ratio of the two differentials, i.e.
$$
\frac{dx}{dv} = \frac{\dot{x}(t)}{\dot{v}(t)}
$$
the answer is actually again given in a parametric form. If one wants it as a function of $v$; one needs to invert the function $v(t)$ and substitute it in the expression above. In other words
$$
f'(v) = \frac{\dot{x}(t)}{\dot{v}(t)}|_{v(t)=v}.
$$