# Independence of momentum and position for Hamiltonians

Tags: classical-mechanics, coordinate-systems, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space

This question might be a replication but I could not find an answers till now.

Why are $(x,p)$ independent in the Hamiltonian formulation?

I'm interested in the independence of $(x,p)$ in the Hamiltonian, specifically under symmetry transformations.

A symmetry transformation should leaf the equations of motion, the Euler-Lagrange equations ($ELG$), form invariant.
Lets say if $\phi$ is a symmetry transformation then $x'=\phi(x,\dot{x},t)$ we demand that $ELG(x) = ELG(x'(x)$). This leads us to the invariance condition state in Noether theorem that the Lagrangian should transform as

$$
\frac{dt'}{dt} L(x' , \frac{d x'}{d t'}, t') |_{x'=\phi(x)} = L(x,\dot{x},t) + \frac{d}{dt} W
$$

Now let us look at the Hamiltonian. I understand that the first Hamilton equation giving the connection between $p$ and $\dot{x}$ is a result of the Legendre transformation. Therefore the variation to derive the Hamilton equations is "trivial" for $\delta p$.

If i demand that $(x,p)$ are independent i can transform them independently. Lets consider now a free particle with $H(x,p,t)=p^2/2m$. Under a coordinate transformation of $x'=\phi(x,t)$ this Hamiltonian is invariant, $H(x',p,t)=H(\phi(x),p,t) = H(x,p,t) $.

So i would get that $\dot{x} = \frac{d}{dt} \phi(x) =p/m$, which look wrong.
Therefore i would conclude that $p$ can not be transformed independently of $x$, due to the condition given by the Legendre transformation.

Another point of confusion is that the action we consider for the Lagrangian gets curves in real space. These curves are functions $x(t): \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^d $. The Legrendre transformation between Lagrangian and Hamiltonian should be involutive. But if $(x,p)$ are independet then the curves are $(x,p)(t): \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^d \times \mathbb{R}^d$. So the transformation should not be involutive anymore, since we need to map this again to $\mathbb{R}^d$ functions.

Comment: isn't this the same problem as having $x,\dot{x}$ be independent in Lagrangian formulation? Why are you not confused there?

Comment: Related Lagrangian question: [Calculus of variations — how does it make sense to vary the position and the velocity independently?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/885/2451)

Comment: @Umaxo,i don't think so because a transformation in $x$ induces a transformation in $dx/dt$ on any curve. I understand that $x$ and $\dot{x}$ are independent for the Lagrangian but the transformations we consider are transformations of the curves.

Comment: @Qmechanic, I'm totally with the answer of Greg Graviton and his last comment. I don't think that the comment by gented is correct as shown in the answer of grizzly adam below. My problem is that we consider the curves as explict functions of time when we take the variation. But i will have a closer look at the other answers.