# Deriving Euler-Lagrange equation

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, differentiation, variational-principle, variational-calculus

[image]

I have derive the Euler-Lagrange equation which is equation (2) for a condition in which generalised velocity is independent on the generalised coordinate but when generalised velocity is dependent on the generalised coordinate then we get a familiar Euler-Lagrange equation which is equation (3).

Is equation (2)  a valid Euler-Lagrange equation?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/885/2451 and links therein.

Comment: " when generalized velocity is dependent on the generalized coordinate " then you get non holonomic constraint equations.

Comment: @Eli so equation (2) is non-holonomic constraint equation?

Comment: $q$ and $\dot{q}$ are independent variables, so the relation $\frac{\partial L}{\partial q}= \frac{\partial L}{\partial q}\frac{\partial q}{\partial q}+\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}}\frac{\partial \dot{q}}{\partial q}$ is meaningless. One doesn't substitute equation of motion to derive EL eqn of motion, rather $\dot{q}$ as function of $q$ is derived from solving EL eqn