# Regarding independence of generalized co-ordinates

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, coordinate-systems, hamiltonian-formalism, constrained-dynamics

In the general scheme of classical mechanics, for a given set of variables, say $\{q_i,p_i\}$, we always impose the conditions, that these variables are independent, that is,
$$\frac{\partial q_i}{
\partial q_j}=\delta_{ij}.$$
Now, is it really justified in general? Since, they always have some implicit dependency depending on the problem, and moreover, this holds for conjugate momenta too.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a helpful comment is that when given a system of $N$ point particles with $3N-n$ [holonomic constraints](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holonomic_constraints), and when we say that the [generalized coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_coordinates) and their generalized velocities $(q^1,\ldots,q^n,v^1,\dots,v^n)$ are $2n$ *independent* variables, we mean *before* imposing the EOM, i.e. [Lagrange equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_mechanics), which are $n$ 2nd-order [ODE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_differential_equation)s. *After* solving the ODEs they are no longer independent. See also [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/885/2451) related Phys.SE post.

Answer (score 0):

Given a set of coordinates $\mathbf x$, the partial derivative of a function with respect to the coordinate $x_i$ is defined by varying $x_i$ while holding the other coordinates fixed.  Explicitly,

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} = \lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x_1,\ldots,\color{red}{x_i+\epsilon},\ldots) - f(x_1,\ldots,\color{red}{x_i},\ldots)}{\epsilon}$$

If we have that $f(\mathbf x) = x_j$, then this straightforwardly implies that $\partial f/\partial x_i = \delta_{ij}$.

> Since, they always have some implicit dependency depending on the problem, and moreover, this holds for conjugate momenta too.

The generalized coordinates and momenta *never* have implicit dependency on one another. Part of the definition of a good set of coordinates is that in a neighborhood of any point in the space, we may vary any one coordinate while holding the others fixed. If a coordinate is fixed by the values of the others, then the coordinate system itself is ill-defined (at least from the standpoint of Lagrangian or Hamiltonian dynamics, in which the generalized coordinates and momenta are coordinates on a manifold).