# What is the derivative of $z$ with respect to $\dot z$?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, coordinate-systems

Let's say the lagrange function of my system is  $L = T(z,\dot z) - m g z$ and I want to determine the equations of motion.
Why is $\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot z} = \frac{\partial T(z, \dot z) }{\partial \dot z}- 0$ ?

I want to know why the second term is 0 even though it is obviously dependent on $\dot z$, since $ \frac{d}{dt} z = \dot z$. Can I just always treat $z$ as if it's an independent variable for these purposes?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/885/2451 and links therein.

Comment: @Qmechanic thanks!