Partial differentiation assumption in development of equation of motion for Lagrangian
In the book "Quantum Field Theory Demystified", David McMahon derives the equation of motion for the Lagrangian:
$$
L=\frac{1}{2}(\{\partial{_u\phi})^2-m^2\phi^2\}
$$
where $ \phi $ is the field as a function of $ (x_0, x_1, x_2, x_3) $
and $ \partial{_u} $ is partial differentiation w.r.t the contravariant 4-vector.

During the derivation, he says that $ \partial{_u}\phi $ can be treated as an independent variable so that

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial[\partial_u\phi]}(m^2\phi^2) =0
$$
I don't understand this assumption since, just taking $ x_0 $ (which is t), $ \phi $ depends on t so that $ \frac{\partial^2}{\partial^2 t} (m^2\phi^2) $ may have a non-zero value?

Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/885/2451 and links therein.

Note that $\frac{\partial}{\partial[\partial_t \phi]}$ is not equal to $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}$

Yes, that should be $\frac{\partial(m^2\phi^2)}{\partial[\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial t}]}$.  But the point is the same, so thanks for the link to (very useful) discussions.
